# Allow file upload in webview?

Tags: android, file-upload, webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

For Example, http://imgur.com
In the stock browser on an android phone you can press the "Browse" button on imgur.com and navigate to a photo you wish to upload. This works great in the browser. Is there something I should set to true to allow this in a webview?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had the same problem and [here is](http://m0s-programming.blogspot.com/2011/02/file-upload-in-through-webview-on.html) how I solved it.

Comment: Thanks for solution. but it dosnt work for 4.4