# File Upload in WebView

Tags: android, android-emulator, webview

I have been struggling to upload files from WebView. I googled and implemented all suggested solutions (e.g. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944102/android-webview-file-input)), but none work.

I have an HTML page with the following code to upload a file.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  File to upload: <input type="file" name="uploadfile">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" value="Press to Upload..."> to upload the file!
</form>
```

It works fine in a desktop browser like Firefox and built-in browser
of emulator / AVD i.e., when I click "Browse..." button rendered by
 element, browser opens a Dialog
box where I can choose a file to upload.

However, in the android 3.0 emulator / AVD, when I click on "Choose
file", nothing happens, no file dialog is opened!

Comment: You may use this `Webview` subclass which handles file uploads etc. automatically: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Comment: @MarcoW. I tried the AdvancedWebView, but still cannot upload files.

Comment: @jiashie File uploads work on all Android versions except Android 4.4, where there's no chance to get it working. Maybe you're on that version? Otherwise, you can check with `AdvancedWebView.isFileUploadAvailable()` if uploads are supported. And you can share your code and ask for help in the issues: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/issues

Comment: @hiram may i upload a file through iframe in a webview in my android app ?what i need to do that ?

Comment: Use TWA https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa

Answer (score 182):

This is a full solution for all android versions, I had a hard time with this too.

```
public class MyWb extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;  
 private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;  

 @Override  
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                    Intent intent) {  
  if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
  {  
   if (null == mUploadMessage) return;  
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null  
                    : intent.getData();  
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);  
            mUploadMessage = null;  
  }
  }  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    web = new WebView(this);  
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/199/index.html");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()  
    {  
           //The undocumented magic method override  
           //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here  
        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
            i.setType("image/*");  
            MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);  

           }

        // For Android 3.0+
           public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
           mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
           i.setType("*/*");
           MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(
           Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
           FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
           }

        //For Android 4.1
           public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
               mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
               i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
               i.setType("image/*");  
               MyWb.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), MyWb.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

           }

    });  


    setContentView(web);  


}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

//flipscreen not loading again
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
/*@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}*/
}
```

Also I want to add that the "upload page" like the one in this example, wont work on < 4 versions, since it has an image preview feature, if you want to make it work use a simple php upload without preview.

**Update**:

Please find the solution for lollipop devices [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/tree/master/input-file-example) and thanks for [gauntface](https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/10/17/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-webview-in-l)

**Update 2**:

Complete solution for all android devices till [oreo here](https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp) and [this is more advanced version](https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView), you should look into it, maybe it can help.

Comment: @hifarrer you are a lifesaver. This worked nicely. PLUS, for us noobs, COMPLETE code helps understand the placement and how it works rather than just pasting a bunch of functions and then we not know where to put and use them. Thank you for your detailed response.

Comment: How to handle this method after obfuscation ?
I am using same method without obfuscation it works fine but when my app is deployed with obfuscation this methods is never called.
I have keeps this method in proguard
anyone seen this issue?

Comment: It works, but how come the value doesn't update as it should be? That's my test on Eclipse Android API17 emulator.

Comment: The `progressBar` seems unused there. I can see its hiding only, but not where it's activated. I think you'd need to add  `onProgressChanged(...)` to the custom `WebChromeClient` variant for that. (And something like `getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);` into `onCreate`.)

Comment: @hifarrer: It shows a warning that  "The method openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri>, String, String) from the type new WebChromeClient(){} is never used locally". where should i  use this openFileChooser Method . Please Help . Thanks in advance

Comment: This line should be useless:
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
as you then immediately do:
    web = new WebView(this);

Comment: Is it necessary to do setContentView(R.layout.main); at the beginning, given that later at the end you do setContentView(web); ?

Comment: And what's the approach for 4.4+?

Comment: It is available on 4.4. the signature is just openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadFile, String acceptType, String capture). see 4.1 overload in example above

Comment: I need a solution which works for SDKs from 4.0 to Lollipop. I have two devices (Note 2 and Nexus 5). And the above code works on none.

Comment: Can anyone help me with android 4.4 ?

Comment: @StevenMarkFord : What is the workaround for android 4.4. Kindly help. Its been days now

Comment: This immediately crashes when I run the app. Is anyone else having this issue? I am using android studio targeting devices from sdk 15 to 22.

Comment: I have implemented the above said code, after that I am able to open file browser but can't select file. Nothing happens on tapping on anyfile and its shown grayed out as well (like disabled). I've checked on android 5 & 6 both none of them is working for me. Also I have this line in my manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: I've found the solution of this issue myself which I've posted here if anyone wants to see it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751033/android-webview-file-browser-opens-but-file-not-selectable/37772961#37772961

Comment: The complete solution for all android devices till oreo is the best

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, because onActivityResult is never called! Any tips ?

Comment: @hiram may i upload a file through iframe in a webview of android app

Comment: may i upload a file through iframe in a webview of android app

Comment: Above code was not working on Android P 9.0 but after adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in application tag of Android manifest it started working. Maybe helpful for somebody.

Comment: Does this still work and also is it the smae principle when using webviews loaded inside fragments?

Answer (score 139):

**Working Method from HONEYCOMB (API 11) to Android 11**

As updated by swati vishnoi, this works on Pie and above too

```
static WebView mWebView;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
```

**Modified `onActivityResult()`**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
        {
            if (uploadMessage == null)
                return;
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
            uploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
    {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
    // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
    // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Now in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` paste the following code**

```
    WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);

mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
{
    // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
    // onActivityResult attached before constructor
    protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
    {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }
   

    // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
    {
        if (uploadMessage != null) {
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            uploadMessage = null;
        }

        uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

        Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
        try
        {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            uploadMessage = null;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    //For Android 4.1 only
    protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
    {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }

    protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
    {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your full code. Its working fine in *except* kitkat Os.
Will you please provide me any idea how to support in kitkat too.
Thanks

Comment: Perfect answer !! Thank you so much @zackygaurav

Comment: Working Perfectly

Comment: Lines `mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);` and `mWebSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);` generate the error _The method setAllowFileAccess(boolean) is undefined for the type WebView_. According to [Android's official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAllowFileAccess(boolean)) both methods default to true/enabled so I guess these two lines can be just ignored. I'm implementing WebView inside an Activity btw.

Comment: It works correctly in lollipop(I tried). But not working in Kitkat

Comment: Issue was reported https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36983532 for 4.4

Comment: Odd. Onn Android Pie 9.0 I'm not seeing anything after the file is picked. I can pick the file, but then it doesn't seem to upload to the webview

Comment: There are many restrictions in 9.0. Please try to use FileProviders and check if it seems to work for you. Ref - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: According to comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045637/html-input-type-file-is-not-working-on-webview-in-android-there-is-any-way-to#comment94900698_46631047), add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in application tag (manifest file) to make it work in Pie.

Comment: @NightFury You have to do this, if you are trying to access an **http** link. Use **https** instead

Comment: why  not private ?public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;. is their any reason for this just want to now

Comment: Working absolutely fine on 9.0.

Comment: Thanks :) Work fine in Android Pie as well. Only we need to add file permissions before request File.

Comment: Only shows video from mobile.. any solution for this?

Comment: what about choosing CAMERA instead of File?

Answer (score 48):

this is the only solution that i found that works!

```
WebView webview;

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

    }
}

// Next part 

class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    // The undocumented magic method override
    // Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        Cv5appActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Browser"),
                FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify please where should I place this code? and How should I use it?

Comment: As of 4.4 (KitKat), openFileChooser is no longer available, hence approaches that make use of it do not work.

Comment: @nadeemgc In my case, I control the web server too, so I am detecting Android 4.4+, using a different URL scheme (aka "my-app://some/other/arguments") for the upload link, intercepting these URLs in shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), and then showing a picker & doing the upload in native code for that case.  It's not exactly a lightweight workaround.

Comment: Can I upload an image in android 4.4.2 using webview?

Comment: @SteveN, can you provide a snippet ? It would be awesome !

Comment: @SteveN can u explain the work around u used for 4.4 +. I also control the web server like u. Kindly help me solve this issue. it has been days now

Answer (score 35):

In 5.0 Lollipop, Google added an official method, [WebChromeClient.onShowFileChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri[]%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams)). They even provide a way to automatically generate the file chooser intent so that it uses the input accept mime types.

```
public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        // reference to activity instance. May be unnecessary if your web chrome client is member class.
    private MyActivity activity;

    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        // make sure there is no existing message
        if (myActivity.uploadMessage != null) {
            myActivity.uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            myActivity.uploadMessage = null;
        }

        myActivity.uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

        Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
        try {
            myActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, MyActivity.REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            myActivity.uploadMessage = null;
            Toast.makeText(myActivity, "Cannot open file chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}


public class MyActivity extends ... {
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
                if (uploadMessage == null) return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For Android versions before KitKat, the private methods mentioned in the other answers work. I have not found a good workaround for KitKat (4.4).

Comment: in my situation, `uploadMessage.onReceiveValue()` works,and has a close `)`

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I tried to make a new class called 'MyWebChromeClient' with your code, but found that MyActivity was a class that I couldn't import...  I could create my own class called 'MyActivity' but I wouldn't know what to put into it.

Answer (score 18):

I found that I needed 3 interface definitions in order to handle various version of android.

```
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback < Uri > uploadMsg) {
  mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
  i.setType("image/*");
  FreeHealthTrack.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
}

public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback < Uri > uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
  openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
}

public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback < Uri > uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
  openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the last one is required for Jelly Bean, which was the one not working for me.

Comment: How to handle this method after obfuscation ?
I am using same method without obfuscation it works fine but when my app is deployed with obfuscation this methods is never called.
I have keeps this method in proguard
anyone seen this issue?

Comment: It would be better to do it the other way round, i.e. put the code in the last one one which has the richest signature, and make use of its parameters to choose which kind of intent to launch. Then have the other two call the last one with default values for those parameters.

Answer (score 16):

This solution also works for Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich. Seems like Google introduced a cool new feature (accept attribute) and forgot to to implement an overload for backwards compatibility.

```
protected class CustomWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient
{
    // For Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType ) 
    {  
        context.mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
        i.setType("image/*");  
        context.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );  
    }

    // For Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg ) 
    {
        openFileChooser( uploadMsg, "" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify please where should I place this class? and How should I use it? Thanks

Comment: place this class anywhere in your activity & use this code webview.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient());

Comment: http://m0s-programming.blogspot.in/2011/02/file-upload-in-through-webview-on.html

Comment: As of 4.4 (KitKat), openFileChooser is no longer available, hence approaches that make use of it do not work.

Answer (score 16):

hifarrer's full solution is very helpful to me.

but, I met many other problems - supporting other mime type, listing capture devices(camera, video, audio recoder), opening capture device immediately(ex: <input accept="image/*;capture"> )...

So, I made a solution that works exactly same as default web browser app.

I used android-4.4.3_r1/src/com/android/browser/UploadHandler.java. (thanks to Rupert Rawnsley )

```
package org.mospi.agatenativewebview;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        initWebView(webView);
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com"); // TODO input your url

    }

    private final static Object methodInvoke(Object obj, String method, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] args) {
        try {
            Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, new Class[] { boolean.class });
            m.invoke(obj, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void initWebView(WebView webView) {

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginState", new Class[] { PluginState.class }, new Object[] { PluginState.ON });
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.clearFormData();
        webView.clearCache(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        // webView.setDownloadListener(downloadListener);
    }

    UploadHandler mUploadHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == Controller.FILE_SELECTED) {
            // Chose a file from the file picker.
            if (mUploadHandler != null) {
                mUploadHandler.onResult(resultCode, intent);
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        public MyWebChromeClient() {

        }

        private String getTitleFromUrl(String url) {
            String title = url;
            try {
                URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                String host = urlObj.getHost();
                if (host != null && !host.isEmpty()) {
                    return urlObj.getProtocol() + "://" + host;
                }
                if (url.startsWith("file:")) {
                    String fileName = urlObj.getFile();
                    if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
                        return fileName;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }

            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;
            // return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {

            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.cancel();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;

            // return super.onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
        }

        // Android 2.x
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // Android 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "", "filesystem");
        }

        // Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadHandler = new UploadHandler(new Controller());
            mUploadHandler.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType, capture);
        }

        // Android 4.4, 4.4.1, 4.4.2
        // openFileChooser function is not called on Android 4.4, 4.4.1, 4.4.2,
        // you may use your own java script interface or other hybrid framework.          

        // Android 5.0.1
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

            String acceptTypes[] = fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes();

            String acceptType = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < acceptTypes.length; ++ i) {
                if (acceptTypes[i] != null && acceptTypes[i].length() != 0)
                    acceptType += acceptTypes[i] + ";";
            }
            if (acceptType.length() == 0)
                acceptType = "*/*";

            final ValueCallback<Uri[]> finalFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            ValueCallback<Uri> vc = new ValueCallback<Uri>() {

                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(Uri value) {

                    Uri[] result;
                    if (value != null)
                        result = new Uri[]{value};
                    else
                        result = null;

                    finalFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(result);

                }
            };

            openFileChooser(vc, acceptType, "filesystem");


            return true;
       }
    };

    class Controller {
        final static int FILE_SELECTED = 4;

        Activity getActivity() {
            return MainActivity.this;
        }
    }

    // copied from android-4.4.3_r1/src/com/android/browser/UploadHandler.java
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*
     * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    // package com.android.browser;
    //
    // import android.app.Activity;
    // import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    // import android.content.Intent;
    // import android.net.Uri;
    // import android.os.Environment;
    // import android.provider.MediaStore;
    // import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
    // import android.widget.Toast;
    //
    // import java.io.File;
    // import java.util.Vector;
    //
    // /**
    // * Handle the file upload callbacks from WebView here
    // */
    // public class UploadHandler {

    class UploadHandler {
        /*
         * The Object used to inform the WebView of the file to upload.
         */
        private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
        private String mCameraFilePath;
        private boolean mHandled;
        private boolean mCaughtActivityNotFoundException;
        private Controller mController;
        public UploadHandler(Controller controller) {
            mController = controller;
        }
        String getFilePath() {
            return mCameraFilePath;
        }
        boolean handled() {
            return mHandled;
        }
        void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && mCaughtActivityNotFoundException) {
                // Couldn't resolve an activity, we are going to try again so skip
                // this result.
                mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
                return;
            }
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            // As we ask the camera to save the result of the user taking
            // a picture, the camera application does not return anything other
            // than RESULT_OK. So we need to check whether the file we expected
            // was written to disk in the in the case that we
            // did not get an intent returned but did get a RESULT_OK. If it was,
            // we assume that this result has came back from the camera.
            if (result == null && intent == null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                File cameraFile = new File(mCameraFilePath);
                if (cameraFile.exists()) {
                    result = Uri.fromFile(cameraFile);
                    // Broadcast to the media scanner that we have a new photo
                    // so it will be added into the gallery for the user.
                    mController.getActivity().sendBroadcast(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, result));
                }
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mHandled = true;
            mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
        }
        void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            final String imageMimeType = "image/*";
            final String videoMimeType = "video/*";
            final String audioMimeType = "audio/*";
            final String mediaSourceKey = "capture";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamera = "camera";
            final String mediaSourceValueFileSystem = "filesystem";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamcorder = "camcorder";
            final String mediaSourceValueMicrophone = "microphone";
            // According to the spec, media source can be 'filesystem' or 'camera' or 'camcorder'
            // or 'microphone' and the default value should be 'filesystem'.
            String mediaSource = mediaSourceValueFileSystem;
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                // Already a file picker operation in progress.
                return;
            }
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Parse the accept type.
            String params[] = acceptType.split(";");
            String mimeType = params[0];
            if (capture.length() > 0) {
                mediaSource = capture;
            }
            if (capture.equals(mediaSourceValueFileSystem)) {
                // To maintain backwards compatibility with the previous implementation
                // of the media capture API, if the value of the 'capture' attribute is
                // "filesystem", we should examine the accept-type for a MIME type that
                // may specify a different capture value.
                for (String p : params) {
                    String[] keyValue = p.split("=");
                    if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                        // Process key=value parameters.
                        if (mediaSourceKey.equals(keyValue[0])) {
                            mediaSource = keyValue[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Ensure it is not still set from a previous upload.
            mCameraFilePath = null;
            if (mimeType.equals(imageMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamera)) {
                    // Specified 'image/*' and requested the camera, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camera directly.
                    startActivity(createCameraIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'image/*', capture=filesystem, or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show a traditional picker filetered on accept type
                    // so launch an intent for both the Camera and image/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(imageMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(videoMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamcorder)) {
                    // Specified 'video/*' and requested the camcorder, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camcorder directly.
                    startActivity(createCamcorderIntent());
                    return;
               } else {
                    // Specified just 'video/*', capture=filesystem or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show an intent for the traditional file picker, filtered
                    // on accept type so launch an intent for both camcorder and video/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCamcorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(videoMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(audioMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueMicrophone)) {
                    // Specified 'audio/*' and requested microphone, so go ahead and launch the sound
                    // recorder.
                    startActivity(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'audio/*',  capture=filesystem of an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases so go ahead and launch an intent for both the sound
                    // recorder and audio/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(audioMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            }
            // No special handling based on the accept type was necessary, so trigger the default
            // file upload chooser.
            startActivity(createDefaultOpenableIntent());
        }
        private void startActivity(Intent intent) {
            try {
                mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // No installed app was able to handle the intent that
                // we sent, so fallback to the default file upload control.
                try {
                    mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = true;
                    mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(createDefaultOpenableIntent(),
                            Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e2) {
                    // Nothing can return us a file, so file upload is effectively disabled.
                    Toast.makeText(mController.getActivity(), R.string.uploads_disabled,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        private Intent createDefaultOpenableIntent() {
            // Create and return a chooser with the default OPENABLE
            // actions including the camera, camcorder and sound
            // recorder where available.
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent(), createCamcorderIntent(),
                    createSoundRecorderIntent());
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, i);
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createChooserIntent(Intent... intents) {
            Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,
                    mController.getActivity().getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.choose_upload));
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createOpenableIntent(String type) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType(type);
            return i;
        }
        private Intent createCameraIntent() {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() +
                    File.separator + "browser-photos");
            cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
            mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath)));
            return cameraIntent;
        }
        private Intent createCamcorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
        private Intent createSoundRecorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
        }
    }
}
```

additional string resoruce of res/values/string.xml :

```
<string name="uploads_disabled">File uploads are disabled.</string>
<string name="choose_upload">Choose file for upload</string>
```

If you are using proguard, you may need below option in proguard-project.txt :

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient {
   public void openFileChooser(...);
}
```

**UPDATE #1 (2015.09.09)**

adds code for Android 5.0.1 compatability.

Comment: Can not get it to work in 4.4.2. Have you test it on android 4.4.2

Comment: @Anna openFileChooser function is not called on Android 4.4, 4.4.1, 4.4.2.
This bug was fixed on Android 4.4.3. ref.) [http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220)
but, saddly, many people uses 4.4.2.
I think you may use your own java script interface(see DanelK's answer) or other hybrid framework(cordova, phonegap, agate...).
In my case, I can't modify HTML files on server. So I used Agate WebView Java Script Plugin. [AgateWebViewFileUpload_AndroidEclipse](http://applusform.com/down/AgateWebViewFileUpload_AndroidEclipse.zip)

Comment: @UnknownStack I am also trying to implement agate Webview Fil upload. Instead of htm page I want to set a url to the webview,. How do i do that?

Comment: @tusharnarang Open "assets/moml/ui/webView.xml" file. Then, find AGATEWEBVIEW.src attribute and replace "index.htm" value to your URL.
(ref. https://github.com/applusform/WebViewFileUploadFix )

Comment: @UnknownStack. if i press back button the application will close.where to use this piece of code in your code..public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

Answer (score 15):

Kotlin solution for Android 8:

```
private var mUploadMessage: ValueCallback<Uri>? = null
private var uploadMessage: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null
```

Constants:

```
const val FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1
const val REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100
```

WebView setup:

```
webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest?) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onPermissionRequest")
            requestPermission(request)
        }


        // For Android 3.0+
        fun openFileChooser(uploadMsg: ValueCallback<*>, acceptType: String) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg as ValueCallback<Uri>
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            i.type = "*/*"
            this@MainActivity.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        }

        //For Android 4.1
        fun openFileChooser(uploadMsg: ValueCallback<Uri>, acceptType: String, capture: String) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            i.type = "image/*"
            this@MainActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)

        }

        protected fun openFileChooser(uploadMsg: ValueCallback<Uri>) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            intent.type = "*/*"
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        }

        override fun onShowFileChooser(webView: WebView?, filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?, fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?): Boolean {
            uploadMessage?.onReceiveValue(null)
            uploadMessage = null

            uploadMessage = filePathCallback

            val intent = fileChooserParams!!.createIntent()
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                uploadMessage = null
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return false
            }

            return true
        }

    }
```

And the onAcrtivityResult part:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode === REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
            if (uploadMessage == null)
                return
            print("result code = " + resultCode)
            var results: Array<Uri>? = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data)
            uploadMessage?.onReceiveValue(results)
            uploadMessage = null
        }
    } else if (requestCode === FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return
        // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
        // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
        val result = if (intent == null || resultCode !== RESULT_OK) null else intent.data
        mUploadMessage?.onReceiveValue(result)
        mUploadMessage = null
    } else
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Please, pay attention that our intent variable called "data".

Comment: Thanks! I'd get you a beer

Comment: Thanks! Works with Android 10 too :)

Comment: By any chance do you have a version of this that uses chooserIntent so you can upload an image via the file browser or the camera? Please share if you do

Comment: Awesome answer!!

Comment: Should be the accepted answer in 2021:)   Works with Android 11 too :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving my day :) Why it's not working with Google drive?

Comment: Type mismatch.
Required:
Nothing!
Found:
Uri?
mUploadMessage?.onReceiveValue(result)   Error on result

Answer (score 14):

This is work for me. Also work for Nougat and Marshmallow[image][[image: 2]][[image: 3]]

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static int FCR = 1;
    WebView webView;
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Uri[] results = null;

            //Check if response is positive
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == FCR) {

                    if (null == mUMA) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent == null) {
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if (mCM != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        } else {

            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ifView);
        assert webView != null;

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.loadUrl("https://infeeds.com/");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            //For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
            }

            // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FCR);
            }

            //For Android 4.1+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {

                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FCR);
            }

            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                if (mUMA != null) {
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }

                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {

                    File photoFile = null;

                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;

                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }

                    return true;
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

2019: This code worked for me (Tested on Androids 5 - 9).

```
package com.example.filechooser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // variables para manejar la subida de archivos
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;

    // variable para manejar el navegador empotrado
    WebView mainWebView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // instanciamos el webview
        mainWebView = findViewById(R.id.main_web_view);

        // establecemos el cliente interno para que la navegacion no se salga de la aplicacion
        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        // establecemos el cliente chrome para seleccionar archivos
        mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

        // configuracion del webview
        mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // cargamos la pagina
        mainWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        // manejo de seleccion de archivo
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == mUploadMessage || intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                return;
            }

            Uri[] result = null;
            String dataString = intent.getDataString();

            if (dataString != null) {
                result = new Uri[]{ Uri.parse(dataString) };
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }


    // ====================
    // Web clients classes
    // ====================

    /**
     * Clase para configurar el webview
     */
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        // permite la navegacion dentro del webview
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Clase para configurar el chrome client para que nos permita seleccionar archivos
     */
    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        // maneja la accion de seleccionar archivos
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

            // asegurar que no existan callbacks
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            }

            mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*"); // set MIME type to filter

            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope can help you.

Comment: for onActivityResult method it says call to super missing

Comment: @sumitkanoje Try to put the call to super before the if block: super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

Comment: Worked like a  charm in 2022

Comment: Do we need READ and WRITE STORAGE permissions in the manifest file? It works for me even without adding it (wondering, how!!)

Comment: @Narshim I haven't been working in Android for a long time but I think It's because this code don't access directly to the file system but through the webview, and it's that upload the file to the webpage like a navigator

Comment: It worked for me on Android 10

Comment: @Prasanna Narshim: The file chooser grants you temporary access to the selected files even if you don't have READ_ and WRITE_STORAGE permissions.

Answer (score 11):

I found it necessary to define `public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)`, in Android 4.1. Then I followed Michel Olivier's solution.

Comment: Can you clarify please where should I define this method? and How should I use it?

Answer (score 9):

Ive actually managed to get the file picker to appear in Kitkat, to select a image and to get the filepath in activity result but the only thing that im not able to "fix" (cause this workaround) is to make the input filed to fill out with file data.

Does anyone know any way how to access the input-field from a activity ? Am using this example [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15423907/1071184). Is just this last piece, the last brick in the wall that i just have to put into right place (tho i could trigger upload of image file directly from code.

### UPDATE #1

Im no hardcore Android dev so i'll show code on newbie level. Im creating a new Activity in already existing Activity

Manifest part

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application android:label="TestApp">
 <activity android:name=".BrowseActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Am creating my BrowseActivity class from this example [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15423907/1071184). The WebChromeClient() instance basically looks the same, except last piece, triggering the picker UI part...

```
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;  
private final static int KITKAT_RESULTCODE = 2;

...

// The new WebChromeClient() looks pretty much the same, except one piece...

WebChromeClient chromeClient = new WebChromeClient(){  
    // For Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) { /* Default code */ }  

    // For Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) { /* Default code */ }  

    //For Android 4.1, also default but it'll be as example
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        BrowseActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), BrowseActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

    }  

    // The new code
    public void showPicker( ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg ){  
        // Here is part of the issue, the uploadMsg is null since it is not triggered from Android
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg; 
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        BrowseActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), BrowseActivity.KITKAT_RESULTCODE);
    }}
```

And some more stuff

```
web = new WebView(this);
// Notice this part, setting chromeClient as js interface is just lazy
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.addJavascriptInterface(chromeClient, "jsi" );
web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
web.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
web.clearCache(true);
web.loadUrl( "http://as3breeze.com/upload.html" );
web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
web.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);


@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {  
  Log.d("Result", "("+requestCode+ ") - (" +resultCode  + ") - (" + intent + ") - " + mUploadMessage);  
    if (null == intent) return;  
    Uri result = null;  
    if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
    {  
        Log.d("Result","Old android");  
        if (null == mUploadMessage) return;  
        result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null  : intent.getData();  
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);  
        mUploadMessage = null;  
    } else if (requestCode == KITKAT_RESULTCODE) {  
        Log.d("Result","Kitkat android");  
        result = intent.getData();  
        final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION  | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);  
        String path = getPath( this, result);  
        File selectedFile = new File(path); 
//I used you example with a bit of editing so thought i would share, here i added a method to upload the file to the webserver
File selectedFile = new File(path);  
            UploadFile(selectedFile);


        //mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue( Uri.parse(selectedFile.toString()) );  
        // Now we have the file but since mUploadMessage was null, it gets errors
    }  
}

 public void UploadFile(File selectedFile)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String sName = "File" + rnd.nextInt(999999) + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath().substring(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("."));
    UploadedFileName = sName;
    uploadFile = selectedFile;
    if (progressBar != null && progressBar.isShowing())
    {
        progressBar.dismiss();
    }
 // prepare for a progress bar dialog
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    progressBar.setCancelable(true);
    progressBar.setMessage("Uploading File");
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);            
    progressBar.show();
    new Thread() {

        public void run() 
        {
            int serverResponseCode;
            String serverResponseMessage;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
            DataInputStream inputStream = null;
            String pathToOurFile = uploadFile.getAbsolutePath();
            String urlServer = "http://serveraddress/Scripts/UploadHandler.php?name" + UploadedFileName;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "*****";

            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

            try
            {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

                URL url = new URL(urlServer);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Log.i("File", urlServer);

                // Allow Inputs &amp; Outputs.
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                // Set HTTP method to POST.
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
                Log.i("File", "Open conn");

                outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );

                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                Log.i("File", "write bytes");

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                Log.i("File", "available: " + fileInputStream.available());

                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                Log.i("file", "Bytes Read: " + bytesRead);
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
                Log.i("file repsonse", serverResponseMessage);

//once the file is uploaded call a javascript function to verify the user wants to save the image
                progressBar.dismiss();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        Log.i("start", "File name: " + UploadedFileName);
                        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:CheckImage('" + UploadedFileName + "')");
                    }
                });


                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.i("exception", "Error: " + ex.toString());
            }               
        }
    }.start();
```

}

Lastly, some more code to get the actual file path, code found on SO, ive added post url in comments as well so the author gets credits for his work.

```
/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @author paulburke
 * @source https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 * @source https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 * @source https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 * @source https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 * @source https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Lastly, the HTML page needs to trigger that new method of showPicker (specificaly when on A4.4)

```
<form id="form-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="fileupload" name="fileupload" type="file" onclick="javascript:prepareForPicker();"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAndroidVersion() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent; 
    var match = ua.match(/Android\s([0-9\.]*)/);
    return match ? match[1] : false;
};
function prepareForPicker(){
    if(getAndroidVersion().indexOf("4.4") != -1){
        window.jsi.showPicker();
        return false;
    }
}

function CheckImage(name)
{
//Check to see if user wants to save I used some ajax to save the file if necesarry
}
</script>
```

Comment: Apologize for late answer, dont have any working demo for this one. This was plain research at the time. Sorry :(

Answer (score 6):

Google's own browser offers such a comprehensive solution to this problem that it warrants it's own class:

[openFileChooser implementation in Android 4.0.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r1.2/com/android/browser/Controller.java#Controller.openFileChooser%28android.webkit.ValueCallback,java.lang.String%29)

[UploadHandler class in Android 4.0.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r1.2/com/android/browser/UploadHandler.java#UploadHandler.openFileChooser%28android.webkit.ValueCallback,java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 6):

Found a **SOLUTION** which works for me! Add one more rule in the file `proguard-android.txt`:

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient {
     public void openFileChooser(...);
}
```

Comment: Which version of Android are you using?

Comment: 4.4.4 CyanogemMode 11

Answer (score 2):

have you visited this links?
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dcaf8b2fdd8a90c4/62d5e2ffef31ebdb

http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?tag=android-upload-file

http://evgenyg.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/uploading-files-multipart-post-apache/

[Concise example of file upload via Java lib Apache Commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698059/concise-example-of-file-upload-via-java-lib-apache-commons)

i think you will get help from this

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Pragna. The actual issue is - **the webview is not presenting me the file upload dialog box where I can choose a file to upload**. So, _first_ I need a solution which enables me to display the file upload dialog box, then I can refer to the links you have suggested.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617388/browse-button-required once see this link

Comment: thx 4 ur suggestions Pragna. **None works...** actually one thing I have observed is, overriding openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri>) method of WebChromeClient works in android 2.2, wherein clicking on a <input type="file"> field in the UI, facilitates file selection from gallery, however, same does not work in android 3.0... there4, I thought of trying file upload in webview with flash file upload, but in the android 3.0 emulator flash is not installed by default and to install it market app is not available and so on complications... concluding, solution seems **impossible** with givens!

Answer (score 2):

***Webview - Single & Multiple files choose***

you needs two minutes to implement this code:

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.1'
```

java code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bivoiclient.utils.Constants;
import com.github.angads25.filepicker.controller.DialogSelectionListener;
import com.github.angads25.filepicker.model.DialogConfigs;
import com.github.angads25.filepicker.model.DialogProperties;
import com.github.angads25.filepicker.view.FilePickerDialog;

import java.io.File;

public class WebBrowserScreen extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;
    private FilePickerDialog dialog;
    private String LOG_TAG = "DREG";
    private Uri[] results;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_complain);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new PQClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.loadUrl(Constants.COMPLAIN_URL);

    }

    private void openFileSelectionDialog() {

        if (null != dialog && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        //Create a DialogProperties object.
        final DialogProperties properties = new DialogProperties();

        //Instantiate FilePickerDialog with Context and DialogProperties.
        dialog = new FilePickerDialog(WebBrowserScreen.this, properties);
        dialog.setTitle("Select a File");
        dialog.setPositiveBtnName("Select");
        dialog.setNegativeBtnName("Cancel");
        properties.selection_mode = DialogConfigs.MULTI_MODE; // for multiple files
//        properties.selection_mode = DialogConfigs.SINGLE_MODE; // for single file
        properties.selection_type = DialogConfigs.FILE_SELECT;

        //Method handle selected files.
        dialog.setDialogSelectionListener(new DialogSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedFilePaths(String[] files) {
                results = new Uri[files.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    String filePath = new File(files[i]).getAbsolutePath();
                    if (!filePath.startsWith("file://")) {
                        filePath = "file://" + filePath;
                    }
                    results[i] = Uri.parse(filePath);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "file path: " + filePath);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "file uri: " + String.valueOf(results[i]));
                }
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        });
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                if (null != mUploadMessage) {
                    if (null != results && results.length >= 1) {
                        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
                    } else {
                        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    }
                }
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        });
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                if (null != mUploadMessage) {
                    if (null != results && results.length >= 1) {
                        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
                    } else {
                        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    }
                }
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }

    public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            openFileSelectionDialog();

            return true;
        }

    }

    //Add this method to show Dialog when the required permission has been granted to the app.
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case FilePickerDialog.EXTERNAL_READ_PERMISSION_GRANT: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (dialog != null) {
                        openFileSelectionDialog();
                    }
                } else {
                    //Permission has not been granted. Notify the user.
                    Toast.makeText(WebBrowserScreen.this, "Permission is Required for getting list of files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    public class PQClient extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressBar progressDialog;

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            // If url contains mailto link then open Mail Intent
            if (url.contains("mailto:")) {

                // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                //Open links in new browser
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                // Here we can open new activity

                return true;

            } else {
                // Stay within this webview and load url
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Show loader on url load
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // Then show progress  Dialog
            // in standard case YourActivity.this
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        // Called when all page resources loaded
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ " +
                    "document.getElementById('android-app').style.display='none';})()");

            try {
                // Close progressDialog
                progressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this line showing error 
    import com.bivoiclient.utils.Constants;

Comment: remove this import and set your url onto this:  webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");

Comment: Hi Ahamadullah Saikat, For giving such effort, it works as custom... Not works by default. If any user wants to open by default attachment options in webview how can s/he will do that. Its an work around .

Answer (score 1):

In KitKat you can use the Storage Access Framework.

[Storage Access Framework / Writing a Client App](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#client)

Comment: "Maybe"? Can you provide more context for your post? Please, read [answer].

Comment: Is there sample code to implement it in android 4.4.2 using webview?

Answer (score 1):

---

**Solution:** https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

---

**Solution for Fragent:**

The difference between ***activity*** and ***fragment*** is only in **onActivityResult:**

**Fragment:**

```
lateinit var webViewGlobal: AdvancedWebView private set

class WebViewFragment : Fragment(), AdvancedWebView.Listener {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentWebViewBinding

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = FragmentWebViewBinding.inflate(inflater)
    webViewGlobal = binding.webWiew
    return binding.root
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        webViewGlobal.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

---

**Android 11:**

```
<application
       ...
       android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
       ...
/>
```

---

**Manifest:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Andriod and struggled with this also. According to Google Reference Guide WebView.

> By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not
>   enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored. If your goal is
>   only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine;
>   the user won't need to interact with the web page beyond reading it,
>   and the web page won't need to interact with the user. If you actually
>   want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the
>   Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a
>   WebView.

Example code I executed in MainActvity.java.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Excuted

```
package example.com.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I researched on this issue for almost one month. Everything failed. All codes seen in multiple websites does n't work good. But here exists the best solution

https://github.com/chiclaim/android-webview-upload-file

## Steps

1) Click on clone or download

2) Get the zip fle in your local directory

3) unzip the zip file

4) Open Android studio

5) Goto File ----> Open ---> Navigate to directory where you unzipped the contents.

6) Change the required web url in webView.loadUrl("your url hre"); in MainActivity.java

7) Works good  with version Android studio 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Custom WebChromeClient:

```
class AppChromeClient(private val fragmentWeakReference: WeakReference<WebViewFragment>) :
WebChromeClient() {
private var openFileCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null

override fun onShowFileChooser(
    webView: WebView?,
    filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
    fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
): Boolean {
    if (filePathCallback == null) {
        return (super.onShowFileChooser(webView, filePathCallback, fileChooserParams))
    }
    openFileCallback = filePathCallback
    val webViewFragment = fragmentWeakReference.get() ?: return false
    webViewFragment.launchGetMultipleContents("*/*")

    return true
}

fun receiveFileCallback(result: Array<Uri>) {
    openFileCallback?.onReceiveValue(result)
    openFileCallback = null
}
}
```

WebViewFragment:

```
class WebViewFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentWebviewBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var webView: WebView
    private val chromeClient = AppChromeClient(WeakReference(this))
    private var contentLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String> = getMultipleContentLauncher()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentWebviewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        webView.webChromeClient = chromeClient
        val url = requireContext().getString(R.string.app_domain)
        webView.setting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.loadUrl(url)
        return binding.root
    }


    private fun getMultipleContentLauncher(): ActivityResultLauncher<String> {
        return this.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()) { list ->
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                showToast("No files selected")
            }
            chromeClient.receiveFileCallback(list.toTypedArray())
        }
    }


    fun launchGetMultipleContents(type: String) {
        contentLauncher.launch(type)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked, hope it helps someone.

Added to `protected void onCreate` these lines:

```
    // Initialize WebView and set onShowFileChooser listener
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.revieveWebview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            // Handle error
        }
    });
```

Added some Override inside `protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

```
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Save callback
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            // Create intent to open file chooser for image selection
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");

            // Launch file chooser
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Image");
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 44745);
            return true;
        }
```

And this in public class Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 44745) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(data != null) {
                // Get the selected image URI(s)
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Uri[] results = new Uri[]{uri};

                // Return the selected image URI(s) to the WebView
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
                mFilePathCallback = null;
            }
        } else {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Also I needed this in public class Activity:

```
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun InAppWebViewScreen(
    webpageUrl: String
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            WebView(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                webpageUrl
            )
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun WebView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, url: String) {
    var backEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var webView: WebView? = null

    var fPCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? by remember {
        mutableStateOf(null)
    }

    val imagePickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()
    ) {
        fPCallback?.onReceiveValue(it.toTypedArray())
    }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                        backEnabled = view.canGoBack()
                    }
                }
                webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
                    override fun onShowFileChooser(
                        webView: WebView?,
                        filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
                        fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams
                    ): Boolean {
                        fPCallback = filePathCallback
                        imagePickerLauncher.launch("image/*")
                        return true
                    }
                }
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                settings.databaseEnabled = true
                settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
                settings.allowFileAccess = true
                settings.allowContentAccess = true

                loadUrl(url)
                webView = this
            }
        }, update = {
            webView = it
        })

    BackHandler(enabled = backEnabled) {
        webView?.goBack()
    }
}
```