# Android Browser didn't supporting HTML Form File Upload

Tags: android, html, android-emulator, titanium, android-webview

I've a app an Android 2.1. using webview (Titanium Mobile Platform ). when i try to use html

file upload field, its showing `"Uploads Disabled"`.

[image]

How to solve this. thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

till now it only works with 2.2+ ...and also you will need to provide a file chooser like in this post

[File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

It however won't work in devices earlier than 2.2 :(