# Choose File error in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing webview application with android for my own site. I have module for uploading the photos to the site, So i have a "Choose file" button in the site whichis  not able to click when it is been called from webview. It works well and good in browser. Any solution to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Though it has been a long time since asked, I will try to give a more comprehensive answer than what I found around the web.

Possible solution for you is: [File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

However, I found this article useful as well: [File upload in through WebView on Android](http://m0s-programming.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/file-upload-in-through-webview-on.html)

The problem is caused by an undocumented magic method `onFileChooser` that is not available as an @override, but works fine once you add it.

Answer (score 0):

For others surfing here PLEASE BE AWARE that the undocumented function openFileChooser is now not currently available in Android 4.4+ (KitKat) !!!

Google Engineer:"unfortunately, openFileChooser is not a public API. We are working on a public API in future releases of Android."

See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220 for more info and much gnashing of teeth...