# WebView Android 4.0 file upload

Tags: android, html, file, upload

It's just NOT working.

I'm doing this

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadFile) {
            System.out.println("openFileChooser");
            mUploadMessage = uploadFile;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("file/*");
            PresentationActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    });
```

but openFileChooser is never called.
Any ideas? openFileChooser is marked @hide in Android source code. 
I think its because you should NOT use this method. Is there another possibility to open a fileChooser??

Comment: For Android 3.0+ you need to implement a different method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parameters for openFileChooser have been updated some times.

For Android 3.0 - 4.0, it is

```
public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType )
```

for 4.1,

```
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
```

and for 2.x

```
public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg )
```

You'll have to add all of them to support any devices between Android 2.0 and 4.1.

Comment: Where did you find these?