# File upload button with inconsistant behavior

Tags: c#, android, .net, file-upload, webview

I have a register page that has a file upload button on it. This is a aspx page in C#.

When i run it in a browser it works fine. 
When i run it in a web view in an android app it does not launch the file menu in you android phone.
When i run the page in a browser on my android phone it lanuches the file menu on my phone just fine.

How do i get it to work in a web view.

My asp tag.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="217px" />
```

my android web view

```
case R.id.register:            
mWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);    
mWebView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
mWebView2.loadUrl("www.mysite.com/AndroidAddMember.aspx");
mWebView2.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());           
return true;
```

I tried to implement your code that you suplied. Im getting an error on FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE now.
The error is FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
case R.id.register:            
        //mWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);    
        //mWebView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
        //mWebView2.loadUrl("http://www.bangmeornot.com/AndroidAddMember.aspx");
        //mWebView2.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());   
        mWebView2.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()   
        {   
            //The undocumented magic method override   
            //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here   
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<URL> uploadMsg) {   

            ValueCallback<URL> mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;   
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);   
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);   
            i.setType("image/*");   
            BangMeorNot.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);        
            }   
        });   

        return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the stock browser [uses an undocumented method](http://m0s-programming.blogspot.com/2011/02/file-upload-in-through-webview-on.html) to accomplish file uploads. Here's what you have to do to enable this functionality in your app:

```
mWebView2.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()  
{  
    //The undocumented magic method override  
    //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here  
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  

    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
    i.setType("image/*");  
    MyAwesomeActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);       
    }  
});
```

Note: The exact parameters for this function have changed throughout the various versions of Android. For a solution which works across all Android versions, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview), or try using the parameters listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12746435/663469).

Comment: In my aspx page it collects information for registering and submits it to a database. I want to make that aspx page work not open a file upload ouside of that webview.

Comment: How would i implement that code into my code above. take your function and put it in my first case statement?

Comment: You probably don't need the startActivityForResult(). Just make that startActivity(Intent...)

Comment: @David could you edit your answer to either link to or add methods [from this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953957/webview-android-4-0-file-upload) as a lot of questions seem to redirect to your question

Comment: @user2309862 I've updated the answer with those links you suggested.