# Android webview, openfilechooser termination

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a simple application that gives the option to upload an image (gallery or camera),
I used webview and managed to make it work.

I have a problem when I'm opening "openfilechoosr" dialog and coming back to my app **without choosing** any file (via the back or just clicking my app screen), than my app is not responding anymore (until android restart) and when I relaunch it, it appears as a blank page.

some more information:

The error I'm getting each time I'm trying to open the app after I got out the file chooser without choosing any file (the app will work again after restarting the android):

> java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not
>   supported before the WebViewCore is set up

My Code:
[MainActivity]

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeViewClient());  
webView.loadUrl(url);


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class MyWebChromeViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
        //@Override
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType )  {      
             File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");
            // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
            if (! imageStorageDir.exists()){
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();                  
            }
            File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");  
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file); 

            final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
            for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                cameraIntents.add(intent);
            }


            uploadMessage = uploadMsg; 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
            intent.setType("image/*"); 
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,  FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE); 
        }
```

Please advice.

Thanks Joe.

Answer (score 1):

I Found the problem,

I forgot to add to the "onActivityResult" the case where the result is equals to "cancel" i.e. 0

Answer (score 0):

Also look at [similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724129/android-webview-file-upload/15136924#15136924)

Don't forget to handle Cancel in your dialog and tell WebChrome that selection fisnished.

Answer (score 0):

Return null on the callback, when the resultCode == 0 (back button)

```
mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
```