# Photo upload from Camera not working in Nexus, Android WebView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, android-camera, android-image

I am working on android webview. I am facing problem while uploading the image from `Camera` action in `Nexus 5`. Here, Camera get open, I click the image but then nothing happens,image is not get upload. But it works fine with like Document or Gallery. There are a lot solution and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725814/upload-an-image-from-camera-or-gallery-in-webview). But I am unable to solve my problem. What can be done to solve this issue?

In my menifest file, I include :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In my activity, i include :

```
private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private WebView webView;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

       Uri[] results = null;

        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            }
            else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;

            }

            Uri result = null;

            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;

                } else {

                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

        }
    }

    return;
}
```

For my WebChromeClient, I include :

```
public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{
// For Android 5.0
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFilePathCallback = filePath;

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }

        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

        return true;

    }

    // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

        File imageStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                , "Photo Folder");

        if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        // Create camera captured image file path and name
        File file = new File(
                imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg");
        Log.d("File", "File: " + file);
        mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

        // Camera capture image intent
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");

        // Create file chooser intent
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

        // Set camera intent to file chooser
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

        // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);


    }

    // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    //openFileChooser for other Android versions
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                String acceptType,
                                String capture) {

        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
    }
}
```

What can be done here, so that image get uploaded via Camera action ?

Answer (score 2):

I solve my issue for Camera by changing following line of code in `onActivityResult` method :

```
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null || data.getDataString() == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }
```

I add this : `if (data == null || data.getDataString() == null) {...}`

Comment: what does your createImageFile() method?

Comment: I missed that part. It's been while. You can find the repo here if you want to see : https://github.com/SatanPandeya/file_chooser_webview

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for for a while actually. I've looked in to a lot of repo's and they have pretty much all the same code, but for some reason they're all missing the  `|| data.getDataString() == null` part in the first check.

Comment: adding the the || data.getDataString() == null part was the solution! Great!

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the application tag in manifest