# Mobile view not showing gallery option (android)

Tags: php, android

Am working on responsive website. The mobile view upload image has the "phone gallery" option in iphone, but its not available in Android system.

Not an app. only a responsive site. Please help. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Its not work automatically in android.you have to customize the webview code...refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725814/upload-an-image-from-camera-or-gallery-in-webview

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<input name="userfile" type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.