# How to let user to choose take photo by camera or select photo in phone storage in Android Webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I am using these on Android WebView when I clicked the file button its only let me choose the image that in my phone storage. **What I want is how can I let user choose take photo by camera or select image from phone storage**
Currently only what I can do is **Select image from phone storage**

```
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
            {
                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }

                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

                Intent intent = null;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();

                }
                try
                {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    uploadMessage = null;
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725814/upload-an-image-from-camera-or-gallery-in-webview

Comment: @MahdiRazzaghi cool, I get the answer inside.