# WebView, input of type file, camera and image

Tags: android, image, input, webview, camera

I have been googeling around for quite some time now... but I still cant find a real answer to my question.
The thing is that I need a way for my user to be able to choose to upload a file from gallery or directly from camera once they press an input-element with the type="file".
So if there is any good samples of this out there, then please let me know, ot if you might have a sample that I could take a look at.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void attachFileInput() {

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    i.setType("image/*");
    ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Choser"), 1);
}
```

This method will be in your JSInterface.
Call it as follows:

```
$(".file").live('click', function() {
    mySJInterface.attachFileInput();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was creating a program that uploads file using input tag with android webview. by the way, i'm not an android app programmer.

Please take a look at these references: [Android webview, openfilechooser termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175564/android-webview-openfilechooser-termination) and http://www.cnblogs.com/sipher/archive/2012/09/05/2672361.html.

Steps:

1. Make a menu to with input file request to capture photo - [Android webview, openfilechooser termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175564/android-webview-openfilechooser-termination).
2. But picture was not sending to server and modified imageUri values `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` as seen here - http://www.cnblogs.com/sipher/archive/2012/09/05/2672361.html.
3. So I needed to add permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Manifest.

   ```
   webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
       public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
           this.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
       }
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String AcceptType, String capture) {
       this.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String AcceptType) {
       final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
       final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
       File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"browser-photos");
       cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
       String mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
       imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath));

   final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
   final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
   for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
       final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
       final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
       intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
       intent.setPackage(packageName);
       intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
       cameraIntents.add(intent);
       }

   mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
   i.setType("image/*");               
   Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i,"Image Chooser");
   chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
   MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
   }
   });
   webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
   webView.loadUrl("..............");
   webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());}
   ```

Now. i'm can upload pictures taken by camera with input tag.

**UPDATE: [You can look for alternate methods to solve the same issue](https://infeeds.com/d/CODEmgks/25019/android-smart-webview-open-source-upload)**