# Issue with form upload in StageWebView / WebView on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, browser, air

since several days, I try to find the reason, why my App cannot open camera roll on android.

I have written down an App, which shows via StageWebView PHP generated remote sites. Everything is cool so far. But if I try to upload a file via form, the camera roll doesnt open at Android. On iOS it works perfectly!

The form in my php looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit />
</form>
```

On iOS: The touch at "Select file" opens camera roll to select an image.

On Android: Nothing happens...

BTW: I tested the WebView component @ Android SDK, the same issue. Anyone any idea?

PS: I found the solution for Android SDK at [Android WebView File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724129/android-webview-file-upload)

**But still missing the solution for Adobe Air StageWebView....**

Comment: My problem is different, I have the two options "Take Photo or video" and "Choose Existing", but once a select picture, the file input does not get updated at all! (I'm using Adobe iOS iPad)

Comment: See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306461/stagewebviewdisk-breaks-the-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue is that the  component for file uploads doesn't work in Android webviews anymore! It simply does nothing when you click it, regardless if you use Adobe Air or a native app. Google [deliberately](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220) blocked it in Android 4.2.

I have spent a lot of time recently coping with this problem. The solution for me was to use this ANE, released last week, which replaces the StageWebView and supports input type file fine (tested on android and IOS): https://github.com/myflashlab/webView-ANE

Hope this helps!