# StageWebViewDisk Breaks the File Upload on iPad (iOS?)

Tags: ios, file-upload, adobe, stagewebview, stagewebviewbridge

I'm using Adobe Air for iPad/iPhone application.

I'm also using `StageWebViewBridge` (https://github.com/paleozogt/StageWebViewBridge) as the main web content displaying container.

My application works well for the Desktop version, but the `StageWebViewBridge`'s `StageWebViewDisk` breaks HTML File Uploading feature:

```
<input id="user_avatar" name="user[avatar]" style="width:100%" type="file" />
```

i.e., whenever a file is browsed and selected from either `Take Photo or Video` or `Choose Existing` from the real iPad device, the above `user_avatar` input does NOT get updated at all.

I believe some paths are messed up by `StageWebViewDisk.initialize(stage)`.

You can find the full source of `StageWebViewDisk` here:
https://github.com/paleozogt/StageWebViewBridge/blob/master/StageWebViewBridge/src/es/xperiments/media/StageWebViewDisk.as

And the following code snippet is very suspicious:

```
case isIPHONE :
    /* new iOS 5.0 Data Storage Guidelines
     * https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/
     * https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html
     */
    _appCacheFile = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath +"/\.\./Library/Caches");

    _applicationCacheDirectory = new File( _appCacheFile.nativePath ).url;
    _applicationRootPath = _applicationCacheDirectory + '/' + getWorkingDir();
    _applicationSourcesDirectory = new File( new File( "app:/" + _document_root ).nativePath ).url;
    _appDocsDirectory = File.documentsDirectory.url;

    /* new iOS 5.0 Data Storage Guidelines
     * https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/
     * https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html
     */                 
    _applicationTempDir = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath +"/\.\./tmp");

    // To acomplish the Apple  Data Storage Guidelines Rules delete our TMP files dir at exit
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING, deleteTempFolder,false,0,true );
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deleteTempFolder, false, 0, true);                   

    break;
```

I debugged a lot, and I finally found out that `StageWebViewDisk.initialize(stage)` is causing  issue.

The proof is that, when I don't use `StageWebViewDisk.initialize(stage)`, instead, directly assign the `stage` to `StageWebViewBridge._view.stage`, it works very well.

I'm not familiar with the iOS app/cache directories.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
_applicationTempDir = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath +"/\.\./SWVBTmp");
// It seems "tmp" is being used by the iOS system (such as the html file upload), so we changed to "SWVBTmp";
```