# webview, file input field filechooser doesn't show up

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I have been working hard trying to upload files from a webview.
I tried many solutions but none worked.

http://m0s-programming.blogspot.tw/2011/02/file-upload-in-through-webview-on.html

[Android WebView File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724129/android-webview-file-upload)

filechooser works fine in a desktop browser like chrome when I click the button and the browser opens a dialog box where I can choose a file to upload.

When I use my cellphone to test the program and I click choose file the Dialog box has no reaction

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this Documentation :

> https://infeeds.com/d/CODEmgks/20475/upload-image-file-gallery-or-camera-webv

```
public boolean onShowFileChooser(
     WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
     WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
     if(mUMA != null){
          mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
     }
     mUMA = filePathCallback;
     Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
          File photoFile = null;
          try{
               photoFile = createImageFile();
               takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
          }catch(IOException ex){
               Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
          }
          if(photoFile != null){
               mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
               takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
          }else{
               takePictureIntent = null;
          }
     }
     Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
     contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
     Intent[] intentArray;
     if(takePictureIntent != null){
          intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
     }else{
          intentArray = new Intent[0];
     }

     Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
     chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
     chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
     chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
     startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
     return true;
}
```

Create image file function, as mentioned in the above code we need this to create new temp file to upload.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
     @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
     String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
     File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
     return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
}
```

Comment: there is git project available in the link

Comment: @Anymore : Upvote the Answer for others to refer easily with it

Comment: it says my reputation is less than 15 so do not change the publicly displayed post score