# Android Webview input file chooser code error

Tags: java, android, webview, jfilechooser

I have been researching online how to use file input on android webview when i came across this post but i got too many errors trying to use it please can someone assist me as am new in android and not very sure if am using the code at the right place.

Here is a link to the answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42385128

**Errors that am getting.**

[image: VIew Error Image]

> mUMA (cannot resolve symbol)
>
> Fi (cannot resolve symbol)
>
> mCM(cannot resolve symbol)
>
> FCR  (cannot resolve symbol)
>
> getAbsolutePath() (cannot resolve method)
>
> photoFile (fromFile (java.io.File) in Uri cannot be applied to (Fi))

```
public class AppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView appbrowser;
    private static final String TAG = "AppActivity";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //webview code
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  //other code
}
//I please the file chooser code after the two above codes
//Here in serted both codes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the code documentation.

https://infeeds.com/d/CODEmgks/20475/upload-image-file-gallery-or-camera-webv