# Need permission to access camera in Android web-view?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing a Web App with the help of `Webview` in android studio but having some issue I need to have the access open the camera how can I do that I have given the following permission in **`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

what should I need to do more to open the camera?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your app targeting Android 6.0 and above than add runtime permission

**Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app**

add runtime permission using below code for camera

```
String permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    String[] permission_list = new String[1];
    permission_list[0] = permission;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
}
```

and than handle result like this

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this,"permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
             // perform your action here

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this,"permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

read about [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: thanks very much @NIlesh Rathod I integrate your code to my app get the permission but the specific feature is not working in webview but it works fine mobile browser Chrrome

Comment: I want something specific thing my app is getting the permission but when i tried to open the camera feature from my app that is not opening but when i load the url in Chrrome it works fine what should to do @Nilesh Rathod

Comment: did you get any exception while running from your app

Comment: No App is working fine all the other feature is also working fine only that feature to open the camera is not working, this feature is working fine in Chrrome

Comment: add the code for opening camera with question @PronabRoy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152632/discussion-between-pronab-roy-and-nilesh-rathod).

Comment: Thanks for the only answer I found so far that mentions `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` function. :)

Comment: im experiencing the same problem :" any news for this problem?

Comment: facing same issue any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best way here is to use WebView API to grant and deny permissions.

1. Create class that extends [`WebChromeClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html);
2. Override [`onPermissionRequest()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onPermissionRequest(android.webkit.PermissionRequest))
3. Request asked permission inside your app, or handle request in another way.
4. Also you probably will need to override [`onPermissionRequestCanceled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onPermissionRequestCanceled(android.webkit.PermissionRequest))
5. Set an instance of your client to `WebView` `webView.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);`

Comment: Is it possible for android 4.4.0 KitKat version?

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj I don't know, have not tested it on pre-l

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a Web App using the webView then you should learn about `JavascriptInterface` provided by Android. Go through following links

[Javascript interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html)

[Android webView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

All you need to do is setup javascript call back.call that method from your web page, handle the javascript call back in the Activity/fragment and from there you can open the camera.

You should also check the answer of  @Nilesh Rathod for the run time permissions.

here are the code snippets that will help you

```
private class WebAppInterface {

    public WebAppInterface(Context context) {
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void openCamera(String title) {
        //check permissions and open camera intent;
    }
}


mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "PLATFORM_ID");
```

Comment: Can you help me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63695705/enable-input-file-camera-on-android-webview