# Camera access in web view in android

Tags: android

I have below code added using other stacker over follow solution sites:

```
  mBinding.webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onPermissionRequest");
                
                mPermissionRequest = request;
                final String[] requestedResources = request.getResources();
                for (String r : requestedResources) {
                    if (r.equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE)) {
                       requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {

                           CustomDialogNew customDialog1 = CustomDialogNew.getInstance();

                           Runnable runnable = () -> {
                               customDialog1.dismiss();
                               mPermissionRequest.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE});
                               Log.d(TAG, "Granted");
                               loadUrl(lastUrlLoaded);
                           };

                           customDialog1.init(0, getString(R.string.message),
                                   false, getString(R.string.ok), "", runnable,
                                   null);
                           customDialog1.show(getParentFragmentManager(), TAG);
                       });
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequestCanceled(PermissionRequest request) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onPermissionRequestCanceled");
                //super.onPermissionRequestCanceled(request);
            }
        });
```

Above logic not working when I grant permission after that when I reload the url that time I see black screen for camera,  camera not open as expected.

Any help is apperciated!

Comment: I stuck with above issue any help is apperciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need permission to access camera in Android web-view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837123/need-permission-to-access-camera-in-android-web-view)

Answer (score 0):

In Webview you need to have a method which triggers Android method and by which you can achieve you functionality.
Search about `JavascriptInterface`
Also make sure before using camera ask the relevant permissions.