# Can web-view can upload images,files or any stuff especially doc and pdf files from Phone's Storage

Tags: android, development-environment

> I Have Tried Webview for 100 tyms but i couldn't access my phone's storage to upload pdf from android webview to php based website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724129/android-webview-file-upload)

Comment: @charliebeckwith This Link will access the mobile storage but it won't accept the file from Mobile Storage to Webview.

Answer (score 0):

'''try - file_type     = " start/start"  '''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).