# File upload using <input type="file" (and not forge.file)

Tags: android, html, trigger.io

Using trigger.io on Android one can't upload files using the plain HTML `<input type="file">` element. On iOS this works fine.

The underlying problem seems to stem from the webview not having a native filepicker, and trigger.io haven't implemented one for their webview.

This question shows a solution on native (non trigger.io) apps:
[File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

**Anyone know if this is possible to solve?**

(Without using `forge.file.getImage`, which is what we use now. The problem with `forge.file.getImage` is that the file isn't a normal Javascript File object, can't be uploaded using FormData/XHR2, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the file module to allow the user to select a file to upload which you can then upload using `forge.ajax.request.`

See http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/file.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using `forge.file.getImage` right now, but that brings many problems. Ordinary `File` objects aren't returned, doesn't work with `FormData`, etc., so I'm looking for a plain HTML/JS cross-browser solution.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to do that, unfortunately it is very difficult to do in both a cross platform and efficient way (it isn't really reasonable to transfer the contents of a file to Javascript as a string). `<input type="file">` support was only added to iOS in version 6 which is one reason we haven't used that.

Comment: We're using `File` objects in iOS 6, works fine (uploads, image rotation, etc). No problem in the Android browser either. The only hindrance is the missing filepicker in the webview on Android.

Comment: The problem with that is it doesn't work on iOS 5, which is still a considerable portion of devices, which is why we have the forge.file API which works on all devices we support.

Comment: iOS >= 6.0 has as 86% adoption now (iOS 5 is at about 10%, the other 4% is iOS 4). http://chitika.com/ios-version-distribution-update