# Android Webview: Getting a ValueCallback for an input type file element

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to get a Uri ValueCallback for an input type file element in an android Webview, without the private API call openFileChooser?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, sorry. File uploads within WebView are not a supported part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Wrong they are! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview

Answer (score 0):

This is dealt with in full here [File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

@ksask - this is now fixed in 4.4.3 and above apparently