# Get Image Path on KitKat

Tags: image, filepath, android-4.4-kitkat

Im having problem in my code in KITKAT OS. I want to get/display an image from gallery and decode it if its a higher size and its working fine for API lower than 19. But when I tried my app in KITKAT, I always get a null pointer exception because it returned.

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:62
```

I already look for solutions and found this.

```
input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Its displaying the image but I'm missing one more step, that is to decode it since i cant get the exact file path of the image.

```
Bitmap imgbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options_for_not_toobig);
```

How would I get the exact address of the image in KITKAT or how other way in decoding an image.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if Android version is kitkat:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");         
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
parcelFileDescriptor.close();
```

Go through this link - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a answer in another post where similar issue is lifted. There youll find the method for getting the path in KitKat.
[File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview/25591691#25591691)