# HTML input type 'file' is not working on webview in android. Is there any way to upload file using webview android?

Tags: android, html

this is my browsing code of html.

This is my android code which load html file for browse file and upload on server.

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(AndroidConstants.MAIN_URL());
            toast(AndroidConstants.MAIN_URL());
            webView.loadUrl(AndroidConstants.MAIN_URL());
            webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                        long contentLength) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);

                }

                  public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  
                      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
                      i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
                      i.setType("image/*");  
                        WebViewActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"Image Chooser"), 2533);  
                     }

                     public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                         openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
                     }                   

                     public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                         openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
                     }   
            });


        }
    });

    JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

i want upload video file using html5 on android application.

Comment: Hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58371281/1318946) will help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue has already been asked and answered here: [File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

Also check this:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220

You can use this class: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Comment: @Shahadeo what is the solution ? https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView worked ?

Answer (score 16):

This is work for me. Also work for Nugget and Marshmallow [image: Web View] [image: Prompt to upload] [image: After uploading]

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    WebView webView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode == FCR){
                    if(null == mUMA){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(intent == null){
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if(mCM != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    }else{
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if(dataString != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ifView);
        assert webView != null;
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.loadUrl("https://infeeds.com/");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            //For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FCR);
            }
            // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FCR);
            }
            //For Android 4.1+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FCR);
            }
            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                if(mUMA != null){
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try{
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    }catch(IOException ex){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if(photoFile != null){
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    }else{
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if(takePictureIntent != null){
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                }else{
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack()){
                        webView.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: Above code was not working on Android P 9.0 but after adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in application tag of Android manifest it started working. Maybe helpful for somebody.

Comment: this code is working for me oto have the same feature as Chrome input file handler. Tested on API 29

Comment: thanks. this code is work in android 5, 11 and 12.

Answer (score -1):

This code is working for me.....

Here, no need to ask storage permissions to the user....

```
package app.qarya.in.upsc4u.questions.answers;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;


public class WebPageMain extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    String webAddress = "https://qarya.in/";
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    static int count=0;
    AdView adView;
    AdRequest adRequest;
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_page);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

         MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");



        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading please wait...");
        pd.show();

        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.srl);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.framLayout);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        assert webView != null;
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
        webView.loadUrl(webAddress);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        //adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.inter));
        //interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        //showInterAd();


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView webView,int progress)
            {
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                //setTitle("Loading...");

                if(progress==100)
                {
                    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pd.dismiss();
                    //setTitle(webView.getTitle());
                }
                else if(progress==70)
                {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    count+=1;
                    if(count%5==0) {
                        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                        showInterAd();
                    }
                    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                }

                //Log.d("progress",progress+"");
                super.onProgressChanged(webView,progress);
            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                // make sure there is no existing message
                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }

                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

                Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    uploadMessage = null;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot open file chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }




        });


    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
            if (uploadMessage == null) return;
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data));
            uploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        webView.reload();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        //adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    void showInterAd()
    {
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if(interstitialAd.isLoaded())
                    interstitialAd.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            if(webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            }else
            {
                final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                alert.setTitle("Exit");
                alert.setMessage("Are You Sure you want to Exit.");
                alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alert.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Home", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        webView.loadUrl("https://qarya.in/");
                        alert.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                alert.show();
            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    // Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();

        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public class Callback extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            pd.dismiss();
            if(!url.contains("qarya") || url.contains("facebook.com") || url.contains("twitter.com") || url.contains("linkedin.com") ||url.contains("whatsapp.com"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return true;


        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm new to Andriod and struggled with this also. According to Google Reference Guide [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

> By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored. If your goal is only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine; the user won't need to interact with the web page beyond reading it, and the web page won't need to interact with the user. If you actually want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a WebView.

Example code I executed in MainActvity.java.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Excuted

```
package example.com.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }}
```