# Android WebView File Upload Issue

Tags: android

Appreciate if someone able to assist or guide me how to fix this issue.

The application is working fine however when request user to upload file or image upon clicking it there's no respond nor pop up to upload file or image to H5.

Here's my project code for review

**MainActivity.java**

```html
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    private WebView mWebView;

    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Permission needed")
                    .setMessage("This permission is needed to download files")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", (dialog, which) -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE))
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
                    .create().show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestStoragePermission();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setDownloadListener((url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType, contentLength) -> {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://domain.xyz");
    }

    private static class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**HelloWebViewClient**

```html
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    private WebView mWebView;

    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Permission needed")
                    .setMessage("This permission is needed to download files")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", (dialog, which) -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE))
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
                    .create().show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestStoragePermission();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setDownloadListener((url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType, contentLength) -> {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://domain.xyz");
    }

    private static class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
    <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.package..MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045637/html-input-type-file-is-not-working-on-webview-in-android-is-there-any-way-to