# File Upload in WebView (4.4.2)android

Tags: android, webview

I have read this article below,but the progress bar and upload file don't work for android(4.4.2)
this aritcle seems not update so I post another Question,hope someone know how to solve it.
thanks

[File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

I tried another method of the code below and
it can upload file well but the url bar will appear on the top ,same as I using browser.
So I  added   WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
in order to hide url bar then the file upload button not working.

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Activity mActivity = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Adds Progrss bar Support
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        // Makes Progress bar Visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webview );
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
        mWebView.loadUrl(http://your.url.com);


        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
        {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)  
            {
                //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
                mActivity .setTitle("Loading...");
                mActivity .setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

                // Return the app name after finish loading
                if(progress == 100)
                {
                    financialPortalActivity.setTitle(R.string.yourWebSiteName);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a full solution for all android versions, I had a hard time with this too.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        initWebView(webView);
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com"); // TODO input your url

    }

    private final static Object methodInvoke(Object obj, String method, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] args) {
        try {
            Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, new Class[] { boolean.class });
            m.invoke(obj, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void initWebView(WebView webView) {

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginState", new Class[] { PluginState.class }, new Object[] { PluginState.ON });
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.clearFormData();
        webView.clearCache(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        // webView.setDownloadListener(downloadListener);
    }

    UploadHandler mUploadHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == Controller.FILE_SELECTED) {
            // Chose a file from the file picker.
            if (mUploadHandler != null) {
                mUploadHandler.onResult(resultCode, intent);
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        public MyWebChromeClient() {

        }

        private String getTitleFromUrl(String url) {
            String title = url;
            try {
                URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                String host = urlObj.getHost();
                if (host != null && !host.isEmpty()) {
                    return urlObj.getProtocol() + "://" + host;
                }
                if (url.startsWith("file:")) {
                    String fileName = urlObj.getFile();
                    if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
                        return fileName;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }

            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;
            // return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {

            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.cancel();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;

            // return super.onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
        }

        // Android 2.x
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // Android 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "", "filesystem");
        }

        // Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadHandler = new UploadHandler(new Controller());
            mUploadHandler.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType, capture);
        }
    };

    class Controller {
        final static int FILE_SELECTED = 4;

        Activity getActivity() {
            return MainActivity.this;
        }
    }

    // copied from android-4.4.3_r1/src/com/android/browser/UploadHandler.java
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*
     * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    // package com.android.browser;
    //
    // import android.app.Activity;
    // import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    // import android.content.Intent;
    // import android.net.Uri;
    // import android.os.Environment;
    // import android.provider.MediaStore;
    // import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
    // import android.widget.Toast;
    //
    // import java.io.File;
    // import java.util.Vector;
    //
    // /**
    // * Handle the file upload callbacks from WebView here
    // */
    // public class UploadHandler {

    class UploadHandler {
        /*
         * The Object used to inform the WebView of the file to upload.
         */
        private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
        private String mCameraFilePath;
        private boolean mHandled;
        private boolean mCaughtActivityNotFoundException;
        private Controller mController;
        public UploadHandler(Controller controller) {
            mController = controller;
        }
        String getFilePath() {
            return mCameraFilePath;
        }
        boolean handled() {
            return mHandled;
        }
        void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && mCaughtActivityNotFoundException) {
                // Couldn't resolve an activity, we are going to try again so skip
                // this result.
                mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
                return;
            }
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            // As we ask the camera to save the result of the user taking
            // a picture, the camera application does not return anything other
            // than RESULT_OK. So we need to check whether the file we expected
            // was written to disk in the in the case that we
            // did not get an intent returned but did get a RESULT_OK. If it was,
            // we assume that this result has came back from the camera.
            if (result == null && intent == null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                File cameraFile = new File(mCameraFilePath);
                if (cameraFile.exists()) {
                    result = Uri.fromFile(cameraFile);
                    // Broadcast to the media scanner that we have a new photo
                    // so it will be added into the gallery for the user.
                    mController.getActivity().sendBroadcast(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, result));
                }
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mHandled = true;
            mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
        }
        void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            final String imageMimeType = "image/*";
            final String videoMimeType = "video/*";
            final String audioMimeType = "audio/*";
            final String mediaSourceKey = "capture";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamera = "camera";
            final String mediaSourceValueFileSystem = "filesystem";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamcorder = "camcorder";
            final String mediaSourceValueMicrophone = "microphone";
            // According to the spec, media source can be 'filesystem' or 'camera' or 'camcorder'
            // or 'microphone' and the default value should be 'filesystem'.
            String mediaSource = mediaSourceValueFileSystem;
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                // Already a file picker operation in progress.
                return;
            }
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Parse the accept type.
            String params[] = acceptType.split(";");
            String mimeType = params[0];
            if (capture.length() > 0) {
                mediaSource = capture;
            }
            if (capture.equals(mediaSourceValueFileSystem)) {
                // To maintain backwards compatibility with the previous implementation
                // of the media capture API, if the value of the 'capture' attribute is
                // "filesystem", we should examine the accept-type for a MIME type that
                // may specify a different capture value.
                for (String p : params) {
                    String[] keyValue = p.split("=");
                    if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                        // Process key=value parameters.
                        if (mediaSourceKey.equals(keyValue[0])) {
                            mediaSource = keyValue[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Ensure it is not still set from a previous upload.
            mCameraFilePath = null;
            if (mimeType.equals(imageMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamera)) {
                    // Specified 'image/*' and requested the camera, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camera directly.
                    startActivity(createCameraIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'image/*', capture=filesystem, or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show a traditional picker filetered on accept type
                    // so launch an intent for both the Camera and image/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(imageMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(videoMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamcorder)) {
                    // Specified 'video/*' and requested the camcorder, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camcorder directly.
                    startActivity(createCamcorderIntent());
                    return;
               } else {
                    // Specified just 'video/*', capture=filesystem or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show an intent for the traditional file picker, filtered
                    // on accept type so launch an intent for both camcorder and video/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCamcorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(videoMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(audioMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueMicrophone)) {
                    // Specified 'audio/*' and requested microphone, so go ahead and launch the sound
                    // recorder.
                    startActivity(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'audio/*',  capture=filesystem of an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases so go ahead and launch an intent for both the sound
                    // recorder and audio/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(audioMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            }
            // No special handling based on the accept type was necessary, so trigger the default
            // file upload chooser.
            startActivity(createDefaultOpenableIntent());
        }
        private void startActivity(Intent intent) {
            try {
                mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // No installed app was able to handle the intent that
                // we sent, so fallback to the default file upload control.
                try {
                    mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = true;
                    mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(createDefaultOpenableIntent(),
                            Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e2) {
                    // Nothing can return us a file, so file upload is effectively disabled.
                    Toast.makeText(mController.getActivity(), R.string.uploads_disabled,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        private Intent createDefaultOpenableIntent() {
            // Create and return a chooser with the default OPENABLE
            // actions including the camera, camcorder and sound
            // recorder where available.
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent(), createCamcorderIntent(),
                    createSoundRecorderIntent());
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, i);
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createChooserIntent(Intent... intents) {
            Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,
                    mController.getActivity().getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.choose_upload));
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createOpenableIntent(String type) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType(type);
            return i;
        }
        private Intent createCameraIntent() {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() +
                    File.separator + "browser-photos");
            cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
            mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath)));
            return cameraIntent;
        }
        private Intent createCamcorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
        private Intent createSoundRecorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
        }
    }
}
```

For 4.4.2 Use this. This is a demo application link. download and import in your workspace.
http://applusform.com/down/AgateWebViewFileUpload_AndroidEclipse.zip

Comment: Thanks.I using android studio is this zip for that?

Comment: No its ecli[pse. You can migrate it from eclipse to android studio.

Comment: The main activity is different from you provide in the code area

Comment: So there are two java file?I don't quite understand your code above.

Comment: The link is the fix for 4.4.2.  and the main activity here is for other versions..

Comment: Just copy paste the code above accordingly and everthing will work but not in 4.4.2... The link is a 3rd party webview.. which you can implement accordingly

Comment: These two are 2 comlpete different solution. If one fails try the other one

Comment: where should I enter my url in the import zip file?

Comment: ok see.. go in asset folder.. Find the file choosetest.htm.. OPen that file in notepad and edit it...

Comment: How to set when I open this app and directly to my website?(not click anything)

Comment: <AGATEWEBVIEW id="webView" layout="0,0,720,1230"
     src="index.htm" 
     controls="none" supportZoom="true">


Replace index.htm in src with your url

Comment: Where should add javascriptInterface ?webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJSJavaBridge(), "api"); like this?