# Android WebView File Handling crashing on cancel/back

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm using the following code from another post to enable file handling within a HTML form input (file upload). It currently works perfectly with the camera and uploading from storage, however if I click on the file input, then not select an application or click back I receive the following message

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ClipData android.content.Intent.getClipData()' on a null object reference
```

I think this has something to do with the file chooser expecting data but I am returning a null object as there is no image to upload via html form but don't know how to fix it. I tried the method here ([Cancel a file upload in a Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235580/cancel-a-file-upload-in-a-webview)) but no luck. I get a complete Android crash using the emulator using; `if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)` etc which I think is on the right path.

Method in full;

```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        try {
            String file_path = mCameraPhotoPath.replace("file:","");
            File file = new File(file_path);
            size = file.length();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error!", "Error while opening image file" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (data != null || mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
            Integer count = 1;
            ClipData images = null;
            try {
                images = data.getClipData();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error!", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            if (images == null && data != null && data.getDataString() != null) {
                count = data.getDataString().length();
            } else if (images != null) {
                count = images.getItemCount();
            }
            Uri[] results = new Uri[count];
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (size != 0) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else if (data.getClipData() == null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(data.getDataString())};
                } else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < images.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        results[i] = images.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    }
                }
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
   }
```

I am using SDK 22, tools 25.0.0, minsdk 21, target 22.

I'm still learning Java so any heads up or examples to fix my issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the "data" object is NULL when you call getClipData() method on it

Comment: yes I figured that, I don't know how to deal with it?

Comment: Try to modify this line" if (data != null || mCameraPhotoPath != null)" to "if (data != null && mCameraPhotoPath != null)"

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it has stopped crashing but if I hit cancel and click file input it won't open again.