# Android webview file browser opens but file not selectable

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

HTML Input type file in my android webview was not working for me so I found this solution ([File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)) and implemented the same, now I am able to open file browser.

**But now the problem is I can't select file.** 
Nothing happens on tapping on any file and its shown grayed out as well (like disabled). I've checked on android 5 & 6 both none of them is working for me. 
Also I have these line in my manifest

```
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If someone like to see exact code, I can paste it right here.

Can someone please point out what's wrong with my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I found that the `accept` attribute of `file` HTML tag was doing all this.

My HTML for input type file tag was like this..

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" accept="application/zip,image/png,image/jpg,application/msword,application/pdf,image/jpeg,image/gif,vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">
```

And once I removed the content from `accept` attribute or removed the accept attribute itself, enable the file selection and it resolved my problem.

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" accept="">
```