# Android website in webview, open file upload dialog

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview that points to a website:

```
webView.loadUrl("https://websmash.herokuapp.com/");
```

When the user clicks on a file upload button in the website it should open a file upload dialog on the phone.

Matt Gaunt has provided a fully-functional [example](https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/10/17/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-webview-in-l) using onShowFileChooser(), although the file upload button is in the local index.html file. I've been trying to get this working for a website inside the webview, but to no avail.

What adaptations must be made to get it working when the button is in the website which the webview points to?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview) SO Post. Per the author`s answer code works for all android versions.