# <Input type="file"> not working in my WebView

Tags: android, file-upload, webview, fragment

I develop Fragment WebView Application.
I use upload code in Fragment WebView. When I click `<input type="file">`
it is active nothing. logcat show only this warning

```
05-22 15:59:39.749 31611-31611/kr.nubiz.comn W/cr_Ime: updateState: type [0->0], flags [0], show [false],
```

How can I solve this problem?

**WebView - Fragment**

```
    private void initLayout() {
    handler = new Handler();

    webView = (android.webkit.WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new AndroidBridge(), "android");
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(android.webkit.WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
            super.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view, handler, host, realm);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
            webView.scrollTo(0, 0);

            Integer menu = 0;

            if (url.contains("index")) {
                menu = 0;
            } else if (url.contains("login")) {
                menu = 1;
            } else if (url.contains("myPage")) {
                menu = 2;
            } else if (url.contains("community")) {
                menu = 3;
            } else if (url.contains("debate")) {
                menu = 4;
            } else if (url.contains("vote")) {
                menu = 5;
            } else if (url.contains("guide")) {
                menu = 6;
            } else if (url.contains("board")) {
                menu = 7;
            } else if (url.contains("privacy")) {
                menu = 8;
            } else if (url.contains("Term")) {
                menu = 9;
            }

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(android.webkit.WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            android.webkit.WebView newWebView = new android.webkit.WebView(getActivity());
            newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            newWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            newWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

            newWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

            newWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

            view.addView(newWebView);
            android.webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (android.webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:")) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
                    webView.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
            });

            newWebView.setWebChromeClient(this);
            return true;
        }

        // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
        // onActivityResult attached before constructor
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }


        // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (uploadMessage != null) {
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                uploadMessage = null;
            }

            uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent intent = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            }
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                uploadMessage = null;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //For Android 4.1 only
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(android.webkit.WebView window) {
            webView.removeAllViews();
            webView.removeView(window);
            super.onCloseWindow(window);
        }
    });
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            try {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setMimeType(mimetype);
                request.addRequestHeader("User_Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file");

                String fileName = contentDisposition.replace("inline; filename=", "");
                fileName = fileName.replace("\"", "");
                fileName = fileName.replace("attachment;", "");
                fileName = fileName.replace("filename=", "");
                fileName = fileName.replace(";", "");
                fileName = fileName.replace(" ", "");

                request.setTitle(fileName);
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "파일 다운로드", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "첨부파일을 다운 받기 위해\n동의가 필요합니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 110);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "첨부파일을 다운 받기 위해\n동의가 필요합니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 110);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    } else {
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    }
    startWebView(url);
}

public void startWebView(String url) {
    webView.onResume();
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

        if (null == mUploadMessage) return;

        Uri result = data == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : 
        data.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. So It is self answer. I hope It is helpful other developers.

**WebView-Fragment**

```
    package kr.nubiz.comn;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog;
import com.kakao.kakaolink.KakaoLink;
import com.kakao.kakaolink.KakaoTalkLinkMessageBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

import kr.nubiz.comn.Activity.MainActivity;
import kr.nubiz.comn.Util.ConnectServer;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

/**
 * Created by NUBIZ_APP on 2017-05-24.
 */

public class WebViews extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;
    private android.webkit.WebView webView;
    private Fragment mContent;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout, frame;

    private ConnectServer connectServer;

    private String url;
    private String hasSub;

    private HashMap<String, String> user_Info;
    private HashMap<String, String> device_Info;

    private String able_Push;
    private String device_Id;

    private int startY = 0;

    private ImageButton btn_OpenMenu;

    private HashMap<String, String> hasSubs;

    private Handler handler;

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;

    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    public static final String INTENT_PROTOCOL_START = "intent:";
    public static final String INTENT_PROTOCOL_INTENT = "#Intent;";
    public static final String INTENT_PROTOCOL_END = ";end;";
    public static final String GOOGLE_PLAY_STORE_PREFIX = "market://details?id=";

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private ShareDialog shareDialog;

    private KakaoTalkLinkMessageBuilder kakaoTalkLinkMessageBuilder;

    private KakaoLink kakaoLink;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR = 1;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == FCR) {
                    if (null == mUMA) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent == null) {
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if (mCM != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        } else {
            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Write your Basic Code

        initLayout();
    }

    private void initLayout() {
        handler = new Handler();

        webView = (android.webkit.WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new AndroidBridge(), "android");
        webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

//        webView.setWebChromeClient(new customWebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            //For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
            }

            // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FCR);
            }

            //For Android 4.1+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
            }

            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    android.webkit.WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mUMA != null) {
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateWindow(android.webkit.WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
                android.webkit.WebView newWebView = new android.webkit.WebView(getActivity());
                newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
                newWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                newWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
                newWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
                newWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

                newWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

                newWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                newWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

                newWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
                newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

                newWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

                newWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                    //For Android 3.0+
                    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                        mUM = uploadMsg;
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        i.setType("*/*");
                        getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
                    }

                    // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
                    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                        mUM = uploadMsg;
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        i.setType("*/*");
                        getActivity().startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                                FCR);
                    }

                    //For Android 4.1+
                    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                        mUM = uploadMsg;
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        i.setType("*/*");
                        getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
                    }

                    //For Android 5.0+
                    public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                            android.webkit.WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                            WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                        if (mUMA != null) {
                            mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                        }
                        mUMA = filePathCallback;
                        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            File photoFile = null;
                            try {
                                photoFile = createImageFile();
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                            }
                            if (photoFile != null) {
                                mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                            } else {
                                takePictureIntent = null;
                            }
                        }
                        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                        Intent[] intentArray;
                        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                        } else {
                            intentArray = new Intent[0];
                        }

                        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCloseWindow(android.webkit.WebView window) {
                        webView.removeAllViews();
                        webView.removeView(window);
                        super.onCloseWindow(window);
                    }
                });

                newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

                view.addView(newWebView);
                android.webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (android.webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
                transport.setWebView(newWebView);
                resultMsg.sendToTarget();

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCloseWindow(android.webkit.WebView window) {
                webView.removeAllViews();
                webView.removeView(window);
                super.onCloseWindow(window);
            }

        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new customWebViewClient());

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                try {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                    request.setMimeType(mimetype);
                    request.addRequestHeader("User_Agent", userAgent);
                    request.setDescription("Downloading file");

                    String fileName = contentDisposition.replace("inline; filename=", "");
                    fileName = fileName.replace("\"", "");
                    fileName = fileName.replace("attachment;", "");
                    fileName = fileName.replace("filename=", "");
                    fileName = fileName.replace(";", "");
                    fileName = fileName.replace(" ", "");

                    request.setTitle(fileName);
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "파일 다운로드", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "첨부파일을 다운 받기 위해\n동의가 필요합니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 110);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "첨부파일을 다운 받기 위해\n동의가 필요합니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 110);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        } else {
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        }
        startWebView(url);
    }

    public void startWebView(String url) {
        webView.onResume();
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private class AndroidBridge {
        // If Use AndroidBridge. Code Here
    }

    private class customWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(android.webkit.WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
            super.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view, handler, host, realm);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
            webView.scrollTo(0, 0);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be better if your explain better your anwse and wich changes make it works.