# Upload Photo Button is not opening any windows to choose a file from

Tags: html, image, upload

Hi guys I'm very new to coding(esp HTML5). I wanted to replace the text inside the "Choose File" button to "Upload Picture". I referred to some sources and I followed the steps in it, and I was able to change the text(Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKDvfxiZ4Zw). The idea is basically hiding the "Choose File" button and replacing it with "Upload Picture" . But when I tested it out, there were no windows that popped out to let me choose file from, i clicked and clicked but nothing came out. And below is the code I referred.

```
 <div>
   <input type="file" id="file" style="visibility:hidden" accept="image/*" capture="user" />
   <label for="file"></label>
   <button id="file" onClick="document.getIdByElement('file').click(); return false;">Upload Photo</button>
 </div>
```

Thank you so much in advance and I'm sorry if there's any confusion but I hope I could get some advices here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
<button id="file" onClick="document.getElementsById('file').click(); return false;">Upload Photo</button>
```

It is `document.getElementById` not `document.getIdByElement`

**Here is working code**

```html
<div>
   <input type="file" id="file" style="visibility:hidden"   accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
   <label for="file"></label>
   <button id="file" onClick="document.getElementById('file').click(); return false;">Upload Photo</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working! But now I have a another problem, because this will be incorporated in a mobile app, so i tried launching it but nothing came out. But if i were to use Chrome to try to tap on the Upload Photo it works like a charm. What's the problem here?

Comment: @VentusZXC can you please try now , I removed accept="image/*" so now it should open file explorer

Comment: Yeah I tried, it works, it opens file explorer. But it is not working on my mobile phone...

Comment: Is your phone android or ios , it should have worked

Comment: My phone is Android, running on Android 10. Yes it works on Android web browser, which is Chrome. Because I have an app which does the same thing, it just doesnt work on the app... So sorry for much trouble but it's been bugging me quite sometime as a beginner

Comment: If you are trying on android code editor like sololearn or other editor it wont work there ,

Comment: I'm trying on the an android webview app developed with android SDK..... Do you have any other more convenient way which I can contact you ? I have tons of questions .... haha...

Comment: Yes it dose not works on webview i tried before, i found some question regarding this , maybe it helps , if you are self coding in webview: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106483/input-type-file-not-working-in-my-webview

Comment: I see. Hmm one more question, from the button it opens up a file explorer, is it possible if I disable the file explorer option and only open the camera?

Comment: <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"> Here by this way

Comment: Yea this is what i used before, it still pops out the option to choose between file explorer and camera. What I'm thinking of is, after tapping on the button the camera automatically pops out without the need to select it manually. is that possible?

Comment: It directly opens camera in mine not file explorer after adding accept="image/*"

Comment: @VentusZXC if i helped out then please support by upvote :0)

Comment: It's so weird. Does tht have to do with what Android version I'm currently on?

Comment: yeah I upvoted. But hoping you might give some further advises =) Thanks for the help though