# File Explorer not opening on webview, opening on regular mobile browser

Tags: android, webview

So I've made a WebView for a friend's website for a project, the website includes a file's uploader, which when you click on it on a regular mobile/pc browser it opens the filesbrowser/explorer to look for the file to upload into the website.

But in the case of the WebView I've made, when I click the file uploader it just clicks without lunching the File Explorer of the phone so I can select files I wish to upload.

Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Simo You have to set chrome client for your WebView. Please check below code

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
        // onActivityResult attached before constructor
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }


        // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            if (uploadMessage != null) {
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                uploadMessage = null;
            }

            uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            try
            {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                uploadMessage = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //For Android 4.1 only
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    });
```

Also override onActivityResult like below

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
        {
            if (uploadMessage == null)
                return;
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
            uploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
    {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
        // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Source: [WebView File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

Comment: Thank you I will try implementing this!