# Android webview not letting me open file chooser

Tags: android, webview

When I tap **Choose file** from [this url](http://androidexample.com/media/webview/details.html) in Android WebView, nothing happens. Here are snippets from my code.

**AndroidManifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**WebView Setting**:

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

I have already tried [this link](http://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128) with no success although there is a lot given in this link.

Comment: can you show ur xml and rest of ur code?

Comment: Please refer this all solutions.
[https://stackoverflow.com/q/5907369/3713967](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5907369/3713967)