# I am using external link in my webview but upload file not working,while its working in browser

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

```
public class chatbot extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatbot);

        String url="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/AlfredSample123?s=eH47rDPVWWg.cwA.Uoo.u8EOkEbQwNvi9kk9XQ-LofHpohwdgigWOmOLMKfmkPE";
        WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(webview);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);

    }


}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dClGH.jpg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15423907/3635454

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com, please before post a new question search for it, often you can find questions that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check you `internet` permission in your manifest first .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Then

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
// add here 
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

**Note**

- `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

Support for running special JavaScript (for example: Alert ())

- `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

When you click the hyperlink address, you don't open the browser to access it, but always browse through the page in the app

Answer (score 0):

Check your `storage` permission in manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now set up the `WebChromeClient` for your webView & inside `webChromeClient` allow for permission. If you are using API level 23 you need to request permission at runtime.

```
    wv1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            request.grant(request.getResources());
        });
    }
```