# How to upload file through Android Webview app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Possible duplicate of :**

> [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29045637/16356706)

> [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463911/file-upload-is-not-working-in-android-webview)

> [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

I know, but the reason I still ask this question is **I DID NOT UNDERSTAND THOSE ANSWERS**. And I also know, that it's my problem and those contributors did well. Not blaming anyone.

I'm a beginner at Android Studio and those answers were definitely not rookie friendly. cause I've been starring at them for like 20 hours till now.

Any way, here's the code I have :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webviewid);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
     package com.example.filechooser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;

    WebView mainWebView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainWebView = findViewById(R.id.main_web_view);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

        mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == mUploadMessage || intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                return;
            }

            Uri[] result = null;
            String dataString = intent.getDataString();

            if (dataString != null) {
                result = new Uri[]{ Uri.parse(dataString) };
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }


    // ====================
    // Web clients classes
    // ====================

    /**
     * Clase para configurar el webview
     */
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        // permite la navegacion dentro del webview
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Clase para configurar el chrome client para que nos permita seleccionar archivos
     */
    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        // maneja la accion de seleccionar archivos
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

            // asegurar que no existan callbacks
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            }

            mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*"); // set MIME type to filter

            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Before asking you to explain to me how it works, there was this can't resolve error at `main_web_view`

Comment: Check Your activitymain.xml and make sure webview id is main_web_view

Comment: can't i chanage the `main_web_view` to webview in .java file..?

Comment: Surely you can change it

Comment: what is your Webview id in xml?

Comment: its `webviewid`

Comment: now change id to "webviewid"  in your .java file                                                 mainWebView = findViewById(R.id.webviewid);