# How to make file upload working in in-app browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, webview

I have a web app in which people can upload a file via `<input type="file" ..>` element. This works fine in all common browsers. Unfortunately my web app is reached via a qr-code link. most qr code scanner apps open the link in an in-app browser (webview) and in these the `<input type"file" ..>` button is not working.
Is there a way to have a file upload, which works also in in-app browsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview

Comment: its not duplicate of this. I have no influence on the webviews of the various qr-code scanner apps around there

Comment: What kind of "not working"? Which Android version, and by extension webview, are you targetting?

Comment: When clicking on "choose file" button nothing happens. My website is reached via a qr code. So must users (depending on which qr-code scanner app they use) see my website with the in-app browser of the qr-code scanner app. it doesnt work in any of these i think.