# Upload button in android WebView does not work

Tags: java, android, webview, android-emulator

[this is my picture of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5eOs.jpg)

the button does not work, file chooser does not open, but if I upload from the web, it is going well, but not working in my `WebView`.

And this is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="profilepath" class="control-label col-md-3"><?php echo $this->lang->line('profilepath') ?></label>
   <div class="col-md-4" value="">
      <?php 
          echo form_upload(array(
             'autocomplete' => 'off',
             'name' => 'profilepath',
             'accept' => 'image'
          )); 
       ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

My java code for WebView:

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private static final String TAG = EditActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private final static int FCR = 1;
WebView webView;
private String mCM;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Uri[] results = null;

        //Check if response is positive
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUMA) {
                    return;
                }
                if (intent == null) {
                    //Capture Photo if no imabe available
                    if (mCM != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUMA = null;
    } else {
        if (requestCode == FCR) {
            if (null == mUM) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUM = null;
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint({"SetJavascriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EditActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA} ,1);
    }

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    assert webView != null;

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }

    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        //For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

            mUM = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            EditActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
        }

        //For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
        public void openFileChooser (ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

            mUM = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            EditActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FCR);
        }

        //For Android 4.1+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {

            mUM = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            EditActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), EditActivity.FCR);
        }

        //For Android 5.0+
        public  boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                                          WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (mUMA != null) {
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
            }

            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(EditActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {

                File photoFile = null;

                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                }
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;

            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);

            return true;
        }
    });
}

//Create an image file
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }

                return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(configuration);
}

public class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed Loading App!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: share your android application code

Comment: already added my java

Comment: probably a duplicate question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview )

Comment: Do you really mean an empty `if` statement in your `onBackPressed`? It now has a semicolon `;` right after `if` statement. I suggest the `webView.goBack()` should be under the `if`.

Comment: @taipei i already follow that and no one can work with me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.recyclerviewwithprogress;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class WebViewUpload extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private WebView webView;
    private WebSettings webSettings;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;




    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            Uri[] results = null;
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }
                Uri result = null;
                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        return;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view_upload);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Client());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.loadUrl("https:www.example.com");//your url
    }



    public class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    mUploadMessage = null;
                }

                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    mUploadMessage = null;
                    Toast.makeText(WebViewUpload.this, "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mFilePathCallback = uploadMsg;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg) {
            mFilePathCallback = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
        }


    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public class Client extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // If url contains mailto link then open Mail Intent
            if (url.contains("mailto:")) {
                // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                //Open links in new browser
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                // Here we can open new activity
                return true;
            } else {
                // Stay within this webview and load url
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // Then show progress  Dialog
            // in standard case YourActivity.this
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebViewUpload.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                // Close progressDialog
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Please add a description of what your code achieves and fixes.

Comment: In this code you can upload a file on server using webview