# How to set a Webview to behave EXACTLY as a Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, ckeditor, responsive-filemanager

Like a lot of people, I'm developing a **simple Android app** that is just a **Webview** that opens my full responsive website, just to permit to find it, install it and launch it like a "real" app (I know you know why I'm doing that!). My web site uses **CKEditor** to permit user to create simple html pages and upload their images to put inside their pages. 
To do that I use the **Responsive File Manager** with CKEditor and all works fine if I open my website from Chrome or other browser on my phone (Android 9). But when I launch my Webapp, even if 90% of the site works fine, I have in the log several Javascript errors like:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(305)] "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function" 
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tools' of undefined" (it refers to this source code --> window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(a, e) )
```

and when I try to use the "upload image" or "select image" funcionality it doesn't works due to the above Javascript errors (it does nothing when I click the action button).

I already **enabled Javascript**, **dom storage** and **access to all files and document** using the webview settings, as suggested in other similar questions, but nothing worked for me.

My super-simple Android app:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.responsivefilemanager.com/demo.php");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        this.setContentView(mWebView);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check out: https://github.com/crosswalk-project#documentation/downloads

Comment: Possibly related: [File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5907369/295004)

Comment: Did you find any solution?