# Uploading file using Android web View App Error at MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android

I m trying to create an webapp with file upload possibility.

I have gone through some queries listed in StackOverflow as well for solution no this like

[File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

However when applied the same in my mainactivity, couldn't resolve some errors showing with red underlines.

**Here's my MainActivity.java:**[image: image_for_reference_on_errors]

```
package com.pack.packname;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Handler;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webviewid);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");

                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    }





    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // .... other stuff in my onResume ....
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }


    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
        protected class CustomWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                context.mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                context.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            // For Android < 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have added an image as well to check the errors that are causing as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.pack.packname;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Handler;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE = 1;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webviewid);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView..setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
           @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }
                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;
                Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    uploadMessage = null;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // .... other stuff in my onResume ....
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

           
        
    

}
```

try this code

Comment: thanks for the effort, it pretty much works, but only for one instance ( i have to close and reopen the app to select again) and it doesn't selects the file and returns back empty.

Comment: Bro, i have a problem . mentioned in the comment.  It only for one instance ( i have to close and reopen the app to select again) and it doesn't selects the file and returns back empty.

Comment: why do you want to close the app to select the item again?

Comment: No ,  forget about that, the when click on "choose file" and selects an item in gallery the item is not getting picked up to the form to submit..