# Taking picture/photo with webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I've the below code that is opening smoothly at mobile browser, and give me the options either to take a photo with the camera, or to upload photo from the gallery:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>
```

I'm loading the same at `WebView`, and made the settings as below:

```
webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {

            override fun onShowFileChooser(
                webView: WebView,
                filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>,
                fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams
            ): Boolean {
                var takePictureIntent: Intent? = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                val contentSelectionIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                contentSelectionIntent.type = "image/*"
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        ctx,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        activity,
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                        0
                    )
                }

                val intentArray: Array<Intent?> = takePictureIntent?.let { arrayOf(it) } ?: arrayOfNulls(0)

                val chooserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent)
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser")
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray)
                startActivity(chooserIntent)

                filePathCallback?.onReceiveValue(null)
                return true
            }
}
```

I'm getting the `Image chooser` open correctly as below:

[image]

But, I've the below questins:

1. If I took a photo by the camera how can I return the new photo path to the webview?
2. If I picked a photo from the gallery, how can I retun the path to the webview?

Comment: This is a little odd. No one is really answering this type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

The file you choose is returned by onActivityResult method from activity of web view, you have to override this method in both your activiy and your web view fragment. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview) some helpfull responses.