# Enable upload files in Android Webview Application

Tags: android, file, upload

I have an E-Store with Wordpress WooCommerce and my store working very well I mean all features like product add, product image gallery images upload, etc everything working very well. I have created an Android Webview Application and everything working good but I am not able to upload files like product images files I cant upload. When I access my website via Application there everything works well only I am not able to upload images or any files. but when I access my website on the browser on mobile everything works well including files or images upload everything works correctly.

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.store.storenisa">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.storenis"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.store.storenisa;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String websiteURL = "https://mystore.com/"; // sets web url
    private WebView webview;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if( ! CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(this)) //returns true if internet available
        {
            //if there is no internet do this
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet Connection, Chris",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("No internet connection found")
                    .setMessage("Please Check you're Mobile data or Wifi network.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    //.setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

        }
        else
        {
            //Webview stuff
            webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
            webview.loadUrl(websiteURL);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());

        }

        //Swipe to refresh functionality
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        webview.reload();
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        //Keep webview in app when clicking links
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

    //set back button functionality
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { //if user presses the back button do this
        if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) { //check if in webview and the user can go back
            webview.goBack(); //go back in webview
        } else { //do this if the webview cannot go back any further

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("EXIT")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure, You want to close this app?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }
    }


}

class CheckNetwork {

    private static final String TAG = CheckNetwork.class.getSimpleName();

    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
    {
        NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"no internet connection");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(info.isConnected())
            {
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection available...");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection");
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this Line and Check Please

```
 package com.example.filechooser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // variables para manejar la subida de archivos
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;

    // variable para manejar el navegador empotrado
    WebView mainWebView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // instanciamos el webview
        mainWebView = findViewById(R.id.main_web_view);

        // establecemos el cliente interno para que la navegacion no se salga de la aplicacion
        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        // establecemos el cliente chrome para seleccionar archivos
        mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

        // configuracion del webview
        mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // cargamos la pagina
        mainWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        // manejo de seleccion de archivo
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == mUploadMessage || intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                return;
            }

            Uri[] result = null;
            String dataString = intent.getDataString();

            if (dataString != null) {
                result = new Uri[]{ Uri.parse(dataString) };
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }


    // ====================
    // Web clients classes
    // ====================

    /**
     * Clase para configurar el webview
     */
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        // permite la navegacion dentro del webview
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Clase para configurar el chrome client para que nos permita seleccionar archivos
     */
    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        // maneja la accion de seleccionar archivos
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

            // asegurar que no existan callbacks
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            }

            mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*"); // set MIME type to filter

            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Vijay where to add this line?

Comment: I have added this line in **MainActivity.java** under the Webview Stuff codes and try it but still its not working.. by the way I am not a developer for android apps I have made this application to follow the video from youtube because my website have mobile responsive template so I only need it to show in app that's why I use webview.

Comment: please provide the website link

Comment: Already answered here bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview

Comment: Vijay there's a lot of answers and codes I told you I didn't have much knowledge about android app development so can you give me the exact code for my solution please.

Comment: Now I Updated My Answer ,Please Check

Comment: it showing me some errors `mainWebView = findViewById(R.id.main_web_view);
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable main_web_view
  location: class id`

Comment: Check Your activitymain.xml and make sure webview id is main_web_view

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I have implemented this code in my MainActivity.java and just change the webview id to main_web_view and check the files upload successfully. but there's I am facing some other small issue's like when I hit back button it will close the application so I just want when I click back button it go back If i visit some pages and when it come back to home and i hit back it just ask to close the application.

Comment: 2nd thing is when there is no internet available it show custom error message like there is no internet connection available etc. 3rd when i swap down it will do refresh the page.

Comment: use SwipeRefreshLayout in your activitymain.xml and put inside webview then  Go to Activitymain.java. Add  Some lines of Codes, check this link                                       [link](https://www.journaldev.com/10708/android-swiperefreshlayout-pull-swipe-refresh')

Comment: Lots of compilation error in this answer.