# Can not upload files in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have just a full screen WebView with a web-page where user can navigate. I need to make available uploading files in webview, for example attach files in gmail or send files in messanger. The problem is that now file attaching buttons just don't react, for example in Google Photos:

[image]

I need to work them exactly like in browser when it proposes the user to choose application for file uploading through implicit Intent. I suppose that I should use implicit Intent but don't know how to implement it in webview.

I enabled some necessary permissions and even more:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Please tell me what decision is up-to-date and works for application with single webView.
Unfortunately none of decisions here helped, may be because they are way too old:
[File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore the previous URL and history stack
            binding.webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }

        val myWebViewClient = MyWebViewClient(this)
        binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        val currentUrl = myWebViewClient.sharedPref.getString(URL, "https://www.google.ru")

        Log.d(tag, "sharedPref value: ${myWebViewClient.sharedPref.getString(URL, "")}")
        if (currentUrl != null) {
            binding.webView.loadUrl(currentUrl)
        }
        binding.webView.webViewClient = myWebViewClient
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        binding.webView.apply {
            if (canGoBack()) {
                goBack()
            } else {
                onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyWebViewClient class:

```
val tag = "CUSTOMTAG"

val SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs"
val URL = "URL"

class MyWebViewClient(val context: Context) : WebViewClient() {

    val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        SHARED_PREFS,
        AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE
    )


    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String): Boolean {
        view?.let {
            it.loadUrl(url)
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)

        with(sharedPref.edit()) {
            putString(URL, url)
            apply()
        }

        if (url != null) {
            sharedPref.getString(URL, "")?.let { Log.d(tag, "sharedPref: $it") }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no upload code. Where are you complaining about?

Comment: And beside INTERNET permission there is no code that needs any other permission. What is it that you are asking?

Comment: Sorry, seems I did not describe it clear enought. Uploading can be anywhere. Attaching files in gmail and so on. Now uploading buttons do not work at all, I need to make them work correctly like in browser.

Comment: I also see no uploading buttons in your code.

Comment: Uploading buttons are in web pages opened in the WebView. Any uploading buttons in the web pages don't work. Screenshot attached for example. I don't mean native Android buttons.

Comment: You should post minimal html code with those buttons so people who try to help you can test it out. Elementary Watson..

Comment: I don't know actually:( But does it really matter? I mean my mobile browser doen't need exact HTML codes but it still handles any attach buttons at any web pages. Doesn't it mean that all these attach buttons at all web pages are the same?

Comment: If you are to lazy to post requested code then what do you expect further of us?

Comment: I don't know how to get HTML code of a button on the web page, how can I get it?

Comment: You say that they are all the same. So write your own minimal html code with buttons and test with them first before you post it here. Do you expect from us that we do it for you? Further i see no buttons in your picture but menu items.