# how to call the camera is not through the native object camera, but through HTML

Tags: genexus-sd

we use a component in the sdpanel ,component url is be set to a html file, there just have a file tag in html file( like this input type="file"), we open this html url in smartdevice's webbrowser ,and then camera can be call, but it not working properly in the app that generated by Genexus. we added two user-permission in the AndroidManifest.xml as following，but still no effect. uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" Has anyone had similar problems, and how did you resolve them?

liuhao  19:22:40
1.I think Mywebchromeclient method needs to be rewritten in webviewactivity.java;

2. I follow https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?29656,HowTo%3A%20Compile%20Android%27s%20FlexibleClient,
   adding the following code to oncreate method in webviewactivity.java,

   new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
   . setTitle("hitpoint")
   . setMessage("hitpoint")
   . setPositiveButton("ok", null)
   . show();

3.Call gradlew uploadarchives to compile successfully,but after rebuildall , this messge cannot be shown.
Is there any configuration file that needs to be modified after gradlew uploadarchives?

Answer (score 0):

the following content contains the key points to solve this problem

[File Upload in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).