# Browse button is not working in WebView android in new version

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In my app Webview webpage file upload not working.but in mobile chrome browser it working. what will I need to do for file upload selector working

I have given all permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

showing permissions also in play store
[image]

My main activity code

```
package one.posone.posoneestimatesrj;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
     */
    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
 


    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

       
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
       
        webView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
       
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://srje.posone.one/");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Published in play store also

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=one.posone.posoneestimatesrj

I refered so many topics from stack overflow But I didn't under how I will implement in my case.

Comment: you must implement method to handle that take look at this reference https://stackoverflow.com/q/5907369/4168314

Answer (score 2):

Image/File picker in WebView does not work directly you have to manage it when browse file button clicked, you have to provide `WebChromeClient()` to the `WebView` object like below

```
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .
    .
    .

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            ImagePicker.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .crop()
                    .compress(1024)
                    .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)
                    .start();

            return true;
        }
    });

}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data.getData()!=null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        Uri[] mFileUri = new Uri[1];
        mFileUri[0] = uri;

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(mFileUri);
    }
}
```

For Image Picker I'm using
`implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'` from [Here](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker)

> **Edited Code**

I've edited your code and put that code accordingly.
below is your Main activity code including above code

```
package one.posone.posoneestimatesrj;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
/**
 * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
 */
public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}



private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

   
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
   
    webView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
   
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://srje.posone.one/");

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

        ImagePicker.with(MainActivity.this)
                .crop()
                .compress(1024)
                .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)
                .start();

        return true;
     }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
@Nullable Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data.getData()!=null) {
    Uri uri = data.getData();

    Uri[] mFileUri = new Uri[1];
    mFileUri[0] = uri;

    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(mFileUri);
}
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

And put the below line inside your App/Module level `build.gradle` file inside `dependencies` block like

```
dependencies {
   //other dependencies
   .
   .
   .
   implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. I didn't understand how I will implemented your code to my app. I am very new to this.

Comment: Could not find com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1.  complete error log - https://sharetext.me/oex8gtzdoq